# Image can't be inverted by the "~" operator

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

When `inverting` the image with "`~`" operator, it will cause the following error.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_bytes = b'\x8bE\xd4=\xacF\xdc\xbd\xfc\x02\x1f>=\r\xba\xbd\x0c\x9a\xbd>\x11tP>E,\x10?\x9d(\x03?\xb0\x18\xfa\xbd-$\xd4=#P\\=k\xe9}?\xac\r\x93\xbe\x87\xe1\xfd>\xff0e=C\xdf-\xbcCc\xe4\xbd?ff\xbf\x989\xbf\xbe5\x8ag\xbf\xaa_\x14?\xb7\xd6;\xbe\x9c*`\xbe\xf12\xe2=U\xc5l>)7\xa3>F^\xea\xbe\xc0\\8<\xc5\xb2\x03?\x9c\x8e\x1a\xbf\xe5lV:\x8b\xbf\x98>\x9e\xc5Y\xbf\x93\xec\xe2>e\xd0\x81\xbe\xf8\x94[>\x01S5=\xdb\xab\xb8>\xef\x05\xb6\xbd.\xaaS\xbf\xfaS\xa2\xbe\x14\x0f0\xbe\xed\xaf\x8c>/\xdc\x86\xbf\xb8\x8e\xbb>*\x97\xed\xbeS@\x0f;$c\x82\xbe_\xd5\xb2\xbe)\xa6\xa1=\xe9\xe9\x04\xbe9J\x9a?\x99\xbf\x02>\xcaA\x8d>C\xe73?\xbbgI>\x93\xf8\xea>\x92\xbd\x10?A\x85\x93\xbf\x18Q&?;\x80V\xbe\xe6\xaa;\xbf\x07\x02\xae>C1\x89>F\x12\xb5>\x90\xf6\xbe\xbc\xb2\xf4\x95\xbeo\x0e\xae\xbe\x97\xdfV=\xef\xeb\xe2\xbdNc0\xbf@zx\xbfv\x86Y?\x1c\xc7l\xbf\xe7\x0ed?\x19Wk\xbf\xcb_.\xbd\x17\xdd\xb7=\xb7\xfc\xe1\xbd \x07\xb9=\xaa\xa3\xd3>t\x8f6\xbe\x7fWC>\xa6\x07\x11?iN\x9d\xbd\xa2g\x1d?\xef\xff\x16?\x9b\xde\xf3\xbc\xbdn\x14\xbf\xfe\x9dL\xbe\xb3W0>\x8fqJ\xbf\xcd\xb8\x9e<\xc6\n\xdf\xbeU\x18\x8b>\x1e\xf8\x9c>\x84&\xb9\xbdK\x13`\xbel\xd0B>\x88\xb6\x8e>\xb8`\xa2>2#\\\xbf\xb7\xdb\xaf=\x91\x12\x93>\xbf\xcc.\xbf\xfd\x88\xe3\xbe\xc9\xab\xe6=|`a?3\xfb\x94>\x9d\xb9\x0e?>\xf0\xab>o\xf3\x9e\xbe,\xb3\x11?`V\x1a\xbf\x849\xa8>\xca\x04}?\x96{\xb5=\x0f\x80\xa5>\'o\xef<\x99\xd9\x81\xbe \xed\xa2>\xa3j<?&a~?\xe8R\x05=\xce\xea\xb1\xbef8`>\xc5 \x05\xbf\xb0\xc6\x83\xbeY\x88\x0f\xbfC\xff}\xbeU\xc3\x11>0\x18>\xbf\xbe\x82\'\xbf4\xe9\x93\xbe\x84\xc0\xa7>\xfb\xf6\x8d\xbeI\xbe\xb8\xbd\xd2\x964\xbe\xa5L\xa0\xbe\x93\x1d\x9c\xbe\xac\xea\xb8\xbd\xd5\xf5y?6\x81>?\x01I\xae>\xdc\xd8\x11\xbfHW\x1e?\xdc_\x87\xbe\xd3\x17"?`w\xb3\xbc\xa053>,P8=P\xb50>\x8b\xc4\xba>\t\xbc%\xbe\x13Q\x82>\xba.\x9e=\xc5f\n\xbe\xd9\xc9\xed=\xf7\xf0+?n\x1f\xe5>7\xd1\xdb>\xea\xef"\xbe\xd1/3?x\x15*?.\xdcO>3\x99\x90=8&\xa0?\x9b\xdc#>:>\xd4>\xa3\x9f\xd0\xbe\x16\xc6&?\'@|\xbf\x18\x05\xf2=\x08\xc4~>\x87XY>\xd8=\x19\xbe2\xeb,?-\x08\xaa\xbde\x93\n>n[\xce\xbem\xe0\xa2\xbe\xfe\x1e\xa0>(\xd6?>\xfe\xf9\x14?\xea\x0e\xc9\xbeh\x0c\x94?\xd1m\xc4\xbfS\x0c3\xbe\xb3\x9e@>\xb5`\x82\xbe\x8e\x8b\xd4>\x1c\xa4\xad>\x96(\xfc\xbbp;P>\xb0\xc6\xb2>R\xeb\xc3\xbe\tj\xdd>x\x95!\xbf*\xaa\x1a\xbf\xb8\xa7~>z\xdc\x13?\xcf\xd3Y\xbf\xe5\xcd\x0b>\x95\x12\xfb\xbek\xa5m\xbeB\xbd\x14?\xe6p_>\xe6\xcb\x9b\xbee\xc1&?U\x9d\xb0\xbfjL@?\xc0-N>\x11\x9d \xbcU\xdf@?\xaex%>\xee{\x08?\xa2\xc3k\xbf<\xed\xe5\xbc{T\x96\xbc0"*>w6%\xbfPh\r\xbe\x12y:\xbf\xdd\xaa\xdd=\x17t >\xb4c\xfd==\x84\x10\xbfl\'\x0c\xbd\x9a\x0f\x1d\xbe\xb2\x03\xec\xbe\xf0\xa6\xa3>\xe2d\x00>h\xb8\xfd\xbd7\xac\xa1>J\xa7\xfa=\xe9\xab\x9e>l\xb7/\xbe\xa3`\x05?\xa9\x1e\x85?\x05\x05*?"\xec\xb4>\x0c\xe8\xee>\xbc\xbaS?i\x16d\xbd\xba\xed3>\xd8S[>\x1d\x7f\x94?\x084\xe0\xbd+\n\xb4\xbe\x89HG\xbf\xf1\x93\x0f?\x987\n\xbf\\\x8fs?\xf6\xbe ?\xa8\xca\xf3=\x84\x07U\xberJ\x92\xbe\xc0\xad\xac>\x12MY\xbf\x12{\xf4\xbe\xbc\xc6.?\x9f%\xd8\xbe\xa8\xaaL>y\x99\x95>\x8f\xc0\x07?\xa5\x84\x89\xbe\xd6\xb1\xa3\xbeT\xec\x0c?\xddZ\x88>\xf5\xd3*\xbe\xc1\xa3\xbd\xbd\x853\x91\xbe\xca\x0c\x14>\x11\x18x\xbe:q]\xbf\xfc\xb1\x82\xbf ;\xe6>\xdc;\xcc\xbd\xe9X\x05\xbf\xcf\xcd\xb9\xbfe]t>\xf0\x84\xc1?\x8c\xffM\xbe\xc8\xb5 >\xa5\x9d\xdd=\xe8c\r\xbf\x89\xd8\x1f>\xaf\xe8P\xbfI\\\x83\xbdGH\xe3\xbe\\3\xbf>\xa2\x1b\xd5>\x0c\x1a\x04?\x18\x17\xad?\xf0\r\xc6>\xa2\xc2\x9f\xbd\xe9M\x80?\xa62\x95\xbd9H\xb9>w,\x1a\xbe\xb0ch?\x89"m>\x8ex\x12=\xc2[Z=\xc2\xa3\xc3\xbf\x86dB>\xff\xee\x1e\xbfi\xa4\x9e>(P9\xbe\xa5\xf0\x1d?=\x17U\xbe\xe9\x0e\x18=\xea\xb6\xaf>\xb8t\'\xbe\xca\xbe[\xbf\x7f\xd9\x8f="\x9aL\xbe\xa4\x10?>2\xa2\x9b\xbeb\xbcR\xbd\x15^\x9a=)\xb8\xe7\xbdJg\x03?\xe6\xf6g>#\xde#\xbe\xca\x92\x19\xbe\x8d\x95\\\xbe\x97I\x12\xbe\x9eF\x03\xbf\xc04\xbf=u\xa9\xe9\xbe+\x1b\xb1>\xff\x8bB\xbd\x16V\xde\xbe\x82\x8b\xe4\xbe\xb0\xb8\x88>\x19\xb3\x9b\xbc\x8f\x82\x90\xbc\x7f\x14\xc2=G{\xe5>\x90\x1b\xbd=\xcf\x14c\xbf\t\xf7O>\xe2\xbc_>\x1e"G\xbd\x14]@>\x15G\xce\xbe2\x8a\xa7\xbe\x9b\x033?\x9f\x11G\xbfT\x0e\xbf\xbe\xe2\xc5\xf9>\xb9\xcd\xd5\xbc\xd6#\x96>\x83W\r<!U6>\xe2\xcd\xfa=E\x80\x81\xbe\xa8\xaa\x83\xbdk=B>^\x03\x89>E\xeb\x13\xbe\x07\x8c\x8f?\xbe\xbb\x12\xbe\x9c.\xaa\xbeY\xd6\x04=\xd9\x8c\xa7>7s\'>\xc0\x18\xb0\xbe\xe0)z?\xa1^\xad>1\x96\x8d\xbea\x8c\xba>\r\x04\xb1>\xdf\xa4C\xbf\x05AS?\x07+\r>\xb7L\xa2\xbfw\x83&?\x9e]Y\xbf[+\x15=\x84\xfb\x0b\xbe\xda\x12\xe3>\x9b:e?\x82\x07=\xbe\xe7{\xcd>\xb2\xbae>\xa0Jj\xbf\x86Y_\xbf\xdb\xd58>:a\xcf=\xe7[\x13\xbe\\\x18*\xbfFE\xd1\xbe\x91\xfe\xa9>\xd1\x006\xbfX\x1f:?\xc7\xfd\x87\xbeR\xf3\n\xbf\t5.?\xe4\xe0!?^\xd8.\xbf0\x0c\xb2\xbeK\xf06?I \xab\xbd\xcd\xf7\x15?\xeat\x97\xbe`_\xc9>\r\x88i=\xa5v\x0f?\x91\xe9\xa3\xbeYB\xdb>\xebG6?\xcd\xb2\x06?\x9f\xc7\xc3>\xb7Qg=A\xff\x10\xbf\\^\xc6\xbe\xbd\x83\x11\xbf\x8b;\xee\xbc\xe9c\x88\xbe+V\x92?\x06\xc2p>\xa1\x87\x15\xbfr*\xff\xbe\t\xd5\x98>\x8b\xee+\xbe&H_?\xa6\x009>\xd6\x039\xbf0\x85\x16?\x9d\xd1\x90\xbdDl\x99\xbe\xa5.\xa1>\xa39Y\xbe|\x87\xa5\xbe?r\xb8\xbc\xf2c.>#H"\xbf\xde\\\x89<\x08\x85n\xbe\xe7\xe3\x1e\xbfG\xfc\xad\xbe\xcf\xfc\xfb>\xc8a\xd5\xbe|!\xc8>|5W\xbe\x85\x91\x04\xbf\xaa\x15a\xbeN\x7f\xae\xbe\xe4)=\xbe\x97\x02w<S\x0c\x11=\xdfh\x8a\xbe\xaa\x92\xb4>\xc2\xac\xdd=\xe5\xe1\x1b?\xed\n]>\xf75f\xbf\xc5d\xa4\xbeF\x1f\x9e\xbf\x06\xd8)>\x9c\x7fQ\xbf\xee\x95-?\x94Mv=\xc5\xa8\xff=\x04\xc0\xd4\xbcm\x88\xb3\xbe\x02a^\xbfG<\xa4\xbe+\x16\x8b\xbepl\x83\xbd\x99\x9a\xb4>\xd3t\x02>\x85\x00\xb0=\x89\xcc\xb6=\r\x03\xbd>[\xa4\xc1>\x81\xb6g\xbes")?\x92\xce\x1b\xbe(9 >+\x02u\xbeK,\x10\xbfr\xf6s\xbfe\x96\xed\xbe\xc4\xb3Q\xbdE-a>\x08A\x86?\xa3\x92\x82=\xae\xdf\xb2\xbd\x1f\xea\x0b\xbf\x07\xcb>\xbf)\xf6\xeb>\xf2o\x07\xbeZ4\x85?\x9fN\x8a\xbef\xb6\xb0\xbcy\x12{\xbd%\x0e\xba\xbe\xcd"&>\x1d\xff>\xbf\xc3P\x8c<G\xbf\xb4=\xbd7\x9a\xbe\xe6\xc1\x89>c\xecY?C\xc5\x80=XHD\xbf\xfe\xef\xf6\xbe\xc9\x95\xa4\xbd\xa0\xef\xd4>R\x9a\xb5\xbeVz\xb4>\xb6\x94\xe3\xbc+\xad\xc6>\'\xa5\xd5\xbe\xab\x90\xbb\xbe\xc2%d>\xcc|-?B\x96,\xbe\xa4J\xa5>\x92j\x8e\xbdZ\xb2\x8b?A@\x88?\xc5\xdf\x8e>\xef\x1dH=\xb9\x8e\x13>\xdbK\xcd>\xe2n\x96>\xef(t\xbe\xb0\x7f\r?\\\xa8\xe3>\xedz\x0c\xbf\xa5a\xa3\xbe\xc2\xb4\x80>W1-\xbeD\xb5]>\xad,\x8f>m\x00\x17?XX"\xbe\x8c\xaf\x04\xbf\xe6\xd0\x1a\xbe\xd8\xbb\xeb=\xfe_\xb7<\xff\x12\xcf>;\x9bs>\xd4\xb5\x12\xbe&\xc8\xb7\xbed\xcb\xd2\xbd\xcfb"=\xee.\xf6\xbe\x01\xb5\xf7>:I\xa7\xbd\xb1\x93\x01\xbd\xad4\xe1>\x94\xcb\x88\xbd]\x9d\x80\xbf1\xac\xb9<q\xccL\xbeUsv\xbe\x8a\x9b\xc6\xbc\xa2U5\xbf\xc7\xdb\x1b?,\xd1\x93>\xc7\xa5\x1b>\xaf\xba\x06>p\xb1P?h\xb8\x01=\xee6\x0b\xbf&`)>!\x11\x11?\x9a\xd51?PG\x86>\r\x9bz?\xf6\x81\xdb>!\xc8\xa4>L\x96j>.\x0b\x91>\x94\xec!>\xef4\xcd\xbe\xdf3??\x1a\xff\xa2\xbe|[\x8f>\xac)\xa8\xbe\x89H\x8a?\x85"\x05\xbf\xf7[\xa7>.\xeeW?\x91\xf2\x90>\xa9\x1a\xb2=0\xf1\xe5\xbeG\xbf\x8c\xb9NH\x96?,)\x8f>\x0f\xb1\xd6\xbe4-9>1pH?\x1c\xbd\xe6>!\x82->\xfe\xa0\xf6\xbe\x01\xfd\xc5>\xd020\xbf\x98\xa8\xb3\xbf\xa3\xad\x14\xbd\xf6\xa08?\xcc\x0c\xa7B\xab\xd1\xa8B\xe4$\xa8B\xc4\x999C\xd3\xa69Coq9C\x19\xbf\x1fC\xeb\x8d\x1fC\xfc\'\x1eC\x16I\x17C-\xbd\x17Cn\x8b\x16C,\xbfoBl\xc8pBJ\xb0nBb\xbc\x12B\xb5\x00\x0eBF<\x11B\xa4g\xe4\xbe\xe1\x15V?\xfd\x00\xa5\xbe\xec\x8fb>R=\x04\xbf\xb7u\x98>L\xda\xcf=#\xfb\x1c\xbf\x1672\xbfp\xb6\xbd>\x06w\x91>\x8f\x0c\x87=\xeb\xd3n>\xc9\ri>\xc8+\xee=\xd7H\xb6=\x04\x01\xa6\xbd\xb7r!\xbf@#\xe3>oL\x04\xbfr\xe5?\xbee\x1f\x88=ZM\xe7\xbeg\xf1\x0c\xbf\xa9\xcd)?\xcf\xd5\x81\xbd\xb1\x0b\x19\xbf\x162j>[Q\x0e\xbe\xea\x8b\x94?\x15\xc9\x92>\x9f\xa0\xa8\xbe\x0f~\x10>\xda&\x8d=\xf3\x18\x93\xbf\xdf)\xd8>9@\x00?\xa2|m\xbe\xd3\x1fG\xbfE\x11l\xbd\xe1\x88\x0c?\xa7\xed\xa0\xbe\xdeY\x07>\xac3\x1a\xbe\xee\x1f\xff=$-H\xbeg\x04\x83=CP\xb5\xbe\x02\x06"<\x10j\x8a>\xdf7\xf3=\x1eTl>\\\x88K>P\xbf\x17\xbe\xcb2\x8c>\xf6v\xcc>k\xb8}>gnb\xbfK\x0f3\xbf<uI>>\x98\x90>+z\xe0>\xd5\xdfE\xbf\xcc\n2\xbe7\x1e\x02\xbf\xd3\x91{\xbd\x04*]C\x92\xc0]CMv^C\xd2`~C]\xfb}C\x81\xb4}C\x90\xf6}C\x89*\x7fC\xd1\xf8}C1Y~C\x95\x80}CO\x91~C\xf3"~CsF~C_\xeb}C\x0cCqC\xe8\xe6pC\t\xe3pC\xad\xe8EC<\xa9EC/XFC\x0e:FCK;FC\xcb\xc9EC\xcd}FC\x1a\xcbFC\xe9\x89EC\x0b\x06FC\xc3\x1aFCB\xc7EC\x01\xa2EC\x9ecFC\x12\xd5EC\xa9\xe6ECO>EC\x1f3FC 8FC\x1e\xd9EC\xefjFC\xd7\xfeFC\xe75EC\xc2:ECNx*Cm**Cc\x17*C\x03\xf1QB\x99\xceKB\xefyTB\x9d8\xc8\xbe\xa6\x9d~?\xcc\xf1\x93\xbe\xe5\xceJ>\x1cM\x83\xbb\xba\xdaF>VxC?Y1\x1b?\x94\x9e\xb6\xbd_MK>\xf7\x0b\x89>"\xe3\x07\xbf_*p>\xf5/\t>1\x92\x81\xbf2\xd1\x1b\xbd\xc9;m\xbf\x84\xe6I\xbd\xfc|\x8d?1\xc6h<o\x0b\x19\xbf\xf9\xee\xa4\xbe\x14I\xa8\xbeL7\'\xbfm\xb9\x9b=\xdd\'\x84\xbd\xaf\xa5\r\xbf\xb2\x80\xed\xbe\xb5\xc9\x0e>\x82\xe6\xe1\xbd\xb3\xa3\xdb\xbd)\x1f\x7f\xbfa6"?s\x11\xed>\x8dR.>Co\xea\xbd6\xd9\x85B\xcc\xe7\x86B\xd0\xf9\x85B\xcd\x94\xe6B\xbd\xb4\xe3B\xcav\xe5B\x82%\x90B\xb3\xff\x90BDS\x91B\xdfZ\xe3B\xf8\x80\xe2B\xc0\xa5\xe3B;\xd6"C\xe6\x99#C\xdb\x97#C\xafnbC0(cC\xa8\xfdbCD\xaf}C\x95\xf7~C\x1a\x85~CZ\x1faC\'F`C\xb7\x99`C\x129}C/\x08}C\xe2|~C[\xdd}C\xdf\xc4~C+\xae}C\x9a\x81}C\x9c}~C\x19\xe8~Cm|yC\xaf\x0bzC\x878yC\xab\xa8dC+\x1aeC{\xb7dC\xa9t~CA\xda}C\xef\xc8~C:\xdd~C\xaf\xee}CVc~Cyi\x0cC\x949\x0cC\x98\xf3\x0bCD(\x99>-#\x85>\x97\xb9\x80?`\xef\xcf=\x05&\x92>E\x0bx=\xc0\xb5\x8f> n\xa8>\xb9R\xaf\xbe\x1c\x88\x10\xbf\xd5e\xe6\xbd\xa3\xd6_>Nz\xcf\xbe\x9c\xb3E>\xe4\xdf\xcd>\xc5-,\xbf\xf5{U>\xffA\x81\xbf\xc0\x9b]>Y0\x98\xbdU\x01\xc8\xbf&\xc5r?\x9f\xa7\xcf=\xce\x1f\x15>\xae\xd03>\xe4:v>\xd9\xa1\x8a\xbe\xe8\x8e\t\xbfe\xa5\x08\xbf \x98\xc1>t\xc2:\xbf\x08\xd7b?\x1dA==\x1ck\x00?\xceU\xeb>\x84\xad\r=\x05\xd7\x8f?X\x96\x82\xbe\xd9\xd18\xbf@31\xbe&7\x05?lpw>o\xbe\x17\xbe@*\x95\xb9\x1d>V<Z\x05\xf2\xbc$9\xa3\xbf\xc7\xf2\\?U\xff\x81\xbe0\x17C\xbf\x03\xe71\xbf\xd2\xb6\x89A/\x1f\x81A\x9b[\x84A\xdf\xd6\x82B\xac\xfe\x82B6\xb0\x85BZ-eAH\xb9mAt\x11WA\xe86\x85B#\xac\x86B\xbb:\x87Blm\x85B\xdb\x8f\x85B\xf2V\x86B,\xf8\x86B\x94X\x84B\xa5\xb7\x86B PoB\xf6\x98nBIYjB\xcd\x9d\xa1A\x7fW\xaeAZ\x1a\xa7A\xe6?lC\xbfSlC\xe5\x82kC\x8e+~C\x89\xa2~C\xef`~C\xf8\x1d\xd3B\x1e\xf4\xd2B\xbf^\xd3Bi=\xe6\xbebiZ?W\xc2\xfb\xbe\x1c\x11f\xbetZ]\xbe(\x9f\x93\xbf\x9910\xbe\xe1$\n?\x07\xe4\xad\xbe\x8d9\x83?\x12A>\xbfn.$\xbft\x82\xd1\xbe\x8c\xd9R?"\xd9\xd9=p\xf7\x1e?\xe5\xebX?\xa5tJ>\t\x91q\xbd\xd4p\xd9\xbe\x96\xf6N\xbez\x8c\x97\xbe\xe8.Z\xbf*\x02]>d\xdb\xd0\xbe\x84\x91\xb6\xbe V\xa7\xbe\xa7\xa8i>\xca\x88"=\x99\xe4\x0b?\xceK\x80\xbf_\x95k\xbd\xf2Gy>\xd1\xde\xc1>2\x1a\xf1\xbd\x11\x1c\xed\xbe%m\x1f\xbe"\xf2">HX\xe4=\xf5\xa4\xc2>\x91\xf7\x8d\xbe\x16\xec\xcc>\x02\x8bg\xbe\x03n\x84>\xbe\xca\x94?\x19\x80\xe0\xbe\xe1\xd9\x17?q\x15=?\xdf\xa4]\xbd\x896\x1d\xbeM\xe5h>N\xf7\x07?i\x9c\xaa>\x01\xef\x15?\xc6V\xcb>\x8c\x1cv>\xe5\t\x9c\xbe\xedz\xee>w\xc5<>\x1a\xed\x99\xbd\x1a\x1e\xd9\xbejY4\xbf\xcb->\xbe\xa7$\xaf>\x93\x99D?T\xe4\x0b?\xa4\xb1\xbb>\xa2E\x88\xbe\xfc\xcd\xdc\xbeF\xe9/\xbfH\x08\xc6>)\x8ek?\xb1\xde\xa5BK\x10\xa4B9w\xa5B\xe4*}C|\xcb|C\xd4\xc4|Cy\xe1PC#\xe6PCp\xb3PCQ1\x8dA\xae\xff\x90A\xcd\x9e\x8cA\x83\xa1\x19\xbf2\xa1z\xbf`\rU>z\xc6\x05?=\x89\xb9>\x85\xb9\x8c=~\x18\xc6<`K\x89>\x93\xd2\xf4>\xae\x04p\xbf\xcd\x0e\xcb\xbe \x8f\xa2\xbf\x0b\x15\xb1>O\x9b\xd7=\x82\x04\x04?*\x8b\x04\xbf\xbd])?I\xf3\xf5\xbeTWT\xbf\xb8 \x14\xbfDc,?\x17\xd9\x17?\xf6\x1b`?\x88&K\xbd\x07\x82\x00>8q?\xbd\x85\xca\xf0>\xbd\xec\xd4>9q\xa0=H\x0f\\>X\x8d\x83\xbd\xae\xe0\x04\xbdG&\x0b?\xf1\xd4W\xbf\xa1\xbdY\xbd\x80#r\xbe\xd0\x7f\xe3>\x8a\x19\r\xbf*w]\xbe\xc6\xf6\xc6>.8S\xbe\xb7\xacM>\x1a\xd2\x11\xbf\xe7\xe9\xf4\xbeH\x18=?e@#\xbfJ=c=\x0f35?\x03G5\xbf\x13E!>\'\xe3S?\xb7/\x93\xbd\xc6\xf00\xbf_L\x16>t2\x01?h\xfe\xb8\xbe\x9c\xaa\xa7\xbet\x96\xd4\xbd\x82\xfe\x90>]\x97\x84>\xbe\x18F;\x93\x0c\x1a?\xb7\x1e\xb2<\xa7n\x06\xbf\xaa\xf8\'\xbf\xa9\xe2q>\x88\xc8\n?\x95R\xf5\xbe\xa9\xc7\x9f>\xcd\x07\xb4A\xc4P\xb3A\xfe\xc4\xb3A\n\xa3hC\x9a\xc9hCH\x16iC\xb7\x0f\x7fC\x83h\x7fC\x8c\xf6~CSG\xa7BMa\xa6B\x80>\xa6B\xef^+\xbf8O\xcc\xbd\xb4=\xd3\xbd\x97\x1d\xae>k%\xc2\xbe\xee)\x0b\xbd\x1a\xf8\x85?\x83H\x86\xbf\xd4\xc7\xdf>c\xd3\xd3\xbe\xa4\xf8\x9f>\xdcL\xc8>\x06\xb0\xa5\xbe\xc9\x02\t\xbe\x8c3\xd1\xbdXD\x9b\xbe\xb7\x8e\xd1>\xc6V9?\xe8\x87\xa8\xbf\x103\x1e?\x81\x9e~\xbf\xd4b\r\xbf\xf9\xdco?\xef\x99\x19?\txq\xbe \x82\x00\xbfAb\x18>w\x97C\xbf\x82\xa5\xe9>\xd0d\xd0>\xd1\xbft=\xe6\xdd\xa6:\xd5\x96\x06??\x91(\xbf\xb4N\xad\xbe\xa7\xf6\xd8\xbe5<-\xbf\xba\xbe\x9b\xbc\xb7q\n>\xecL\x1d=\x00\xca4\xbf\xa3f{\xbe\xfe\xc6\x19\xbe\x1c\xb1\x1a\xbf\x08\xaeB\xbf\x92\xa98?\x06\x94\x1c>r\xd9\xe7\xbb\xd8P\x0b?7o\xf8\xbeS\x90C?>\xf9\x17\xbf\x10\xf2\x1c?\xd0U.\xbd\x8fb\x00\xbe\xc3>Q?\xe1\x14\xb4=\xdd\x07j=\x89\xf1\x9d>q\xf7\x8b\xbf\xd2\xc4\x93>\x94sL\xbfXO\x1d\xbf\xb8:\xfd\xbe\x1b\xebH=p\xd3/?=\x98\x0c?O\x1cM?\xf99\xc5>\xcfy\xfd>\x8c\xe7\xb6\xbd\x12O\x0e\xbfR@\x00C\xaf\xeb\x00C>\x0b\x01C\x1fM}Cpo}C`\xb7}C\xd2OnC\x10xmC\xe9\xa5mCv\xad1B\xbc%-B\xf3\x8f/B\xea\xe3\x87\xbed\x89\x1d\xbf\x96%\xb3>\x8a\x8a#?h\x10\xae>\xefx\x12=\xfb\xcb\x91\xbe\xe1\xcf\xcf>A\x96%?I \xdf\xbdbBO\xbfj\xaeb\xbf=\x0e\xcc<\x18\xb4\x87>;c\xef\xbe\xaf\xf5\r\xbf\x1b\xe1-\xbffy\x8c=9*\xaa>rr\xb1=\xb9\xef)?\x18\xab\xd4\xbec$\xd6=\x85\xaco\xbd\x0b*0?p\x99/\xbe\x99\xb4\x0c\xbe\x1e\xb94?\xad\x05P>O\xda9\xbd\x8d)C\xbf\x92x\xc6>"k\x95?:\x9e+>\x08\xdd&\xbf\x82\x9c\x83\xbeJ\x8e\x01\xbcQ}\xb4>n\x82\x1c?\x86#t=\x1f0\xd8\xbe\xa8n\xa3\xbf.3\x1b\xbf\xb9\xc6\x07\xbfq\xb0\xad=)\x9cm\xbe\x93^N?o}F>\xcd\xcf\xd2>&\xc4+\xbd\xc9\x05\xc8>\xb3D.\xbe\xec\xbc\x01>\xa6\x15\xd3\xbd\x1a\xf7#?x\xf3\x13?J\xb3\xea>\x97\x02>\xbe\xc3\x81\x1c\xbdu\x01r\xbe|\n/\xbd\xb7\x84\x1d?\xbb\x0e\xf8\xbeO\x8cp?\xdf\x91b\xbfw\xc0*\xbea\xbe)\xbd\xd0F;\xbf\x8d\xa3\xba>\x80\x98hBb9oBWFlB\x1eDyC\xfa\x87xC\x8b\xddxC*D}CK\xce~C\x18\x99~C\x80\xe2wB\xc2\xd4zB3OvB[)K?\x0b\xa0\x12>\x82!\x15\xbfB \x00>\x00t\xca>G\xb7+?\xdf\xfd\xf4>\xe7\x00\xaa>wZ\x83=L\xd8\x8b\xbe\x0e\xc5\xcc\xbe\x9d\x7f==\xd4KE>\x02\xf4!>\xbe\xb0%\xbf\xbf\xd8\xc8\xbe\x85>\xfb\xbe\xeb\xf9{?.\xdb\xce=@\x84\x1d\xbf=\x8e\xd1>\xd8\xe1\x8a\xbf\xcc\x95o=\x9aK\x85?>\x151?\x07\xac\x03\xbf\xcb\xe2\x17>\xae).\xbe\xa4=\xf7>\xb8\xf7(\xbf2\xd3\xe1\xbd\xedw\x9c=\\\xda\x8d>\xcc5\xe7>g\xb8\x15?\x91Vb\xbf4r\x80?\x8e\x03\xe6\xbeU\xf3\xde\xbe\'\xb4\x85\xbf\xec\'\x98\xbf\x0f\xe3\xba\xbe\xa3_|>+X\xb4\xbe\xaf\xdf\x1c?M\x9d\n\xbf\xa1\x86\xe6\xba\xae\rC?i\xf5U>\xa0Ab>\xda\xb9\xc1=\xa7\xc2\x81\xbe\xcd\x9a\x06\xbf\xcb\xa9\xb5\xbdd\x15\xd3>ed\n>\xa3\xbbp\xbf\xb7\xfat>\xa3\xe6\xd7\xbd\x82\xca\x98?6x\xfd\xbe\x9d.O?\x8d\xb5\xa1<\xd6\x02\xa3>.\xc5q\xbe\xcd\xd7F\xbe\xd8\xcbj\xbe\x0b\xbb\xc0>\xc8.\xa7>i\xe4\xd0\xbe\x00\xcf\xb9>)\xffG=\x9a\xc7\x04C\xa1\xee\x04C\xf17\x05C,\xd3}C\x12\xf2}C\xa8-~C\xcf=:Cj\x7f:C\xda\xad:C\xb7i\x8c@\x8c=\xc0@\xc0\xf4\x97@\xd4K=\xbe\xd3\xa2\xdd\xbd\\o(>s\xcf\xb5\xbf\xd48\xcf\xbe<\xbf\x83\xbfU\x97\xf8<\xfa\x89\x02?\x81%\x7f\xbd$\x7fh\xbfQa\x05=\xb2\x0c\xb9\xbce\x9d\xa1?\xb4\xf4\x02?\xe1<\x7f>;\x8f<\xbf\xa6\xb9\xd9\xbe8\xe9B\xbf\xaa\xc3\xa0\xbf\x85\xb4T\xbd =\x01?\xf1\xb6\xc4>\x1d\xf1\xbb>r\x80\xb5\xbf0i\x06\xbf\xc1\x10t\xbe\x9f\xd4\x92=\t\x19]\xbf2\xe3\x1e\xbe\x08\'#\xbf\xd3K\xf2\xbc\xfep\x96\xbe\xa6\xb7Y><\r_?\xd6j\t=Yy\x07\xbf`\x91e?2\xe2\x1d>r\r\x17\xbe\x9c\xfe[\xbd\xd6\x88\xe8=\x1c\xea\xcb\xbe;\xf7!?j\xc0(\xbe\xb8\xc1\xb6>Uf\xf8>\'\x05E\xbeFA\xc8\xbe\xab}\x8f\xbc\x85\x089<\x07\xb9R?\x023\x19\xbf3\xcd{>\xd85\x07>\x1a`\x02\xbf3\xb6\xb6\xbd&\x94u?\xedY\x8b>\x0e\xa8\x82>}s\xe4\xbd<\x87\x8d\xbe1\x8cy>G\xe9E?\xd3J\x87\xbe\xc2\x0f\xc1?\xea\x1bx\xbe\x95]\xea\xbe\x00x+\xbf\xac\xd1\xb1\xbe\x92\xe5\rA\t\x98\x0fA\x1aL\x10A\x8fOMC\xb2TLC\xc5\xa4LC\x06vxC\\\xc0xC(\xaawC]shB\x95\x0ejB\xda\x0biB\x89.\xa1\xbf6\xcd\xc6>\x8by\x84\xbf\x05\xfa\xd5>\x8b\x1aN\xbdz\xd9&\xbd\xbf\x13\xda>\x9cke?\xe4gl>\x85\xa0P>\xfe\x95\x9f<\xa3\xab&\xbf[^E?c`\xa1\xbe\xe8\xbc\xa6=E\xd3\xe3>\xa7\x7f\xd0\xbc\x89FI\xbd_\xba\xa8\xbf5?Z\xbe\x0e\xban>\x8e\xf1\xf0>\x9f\xe8\x05\xbdQ\x1a\x8b\xbaJ,\x04?\xcd\x0f\x90?\xd1\xd8\xa1>\xa6\xb3y>\xfd^">5\xb1<\xbe\x0c\x08\xce=:l\\>\xd0\xc8G\xbf\xb8\xe2d?\x85\x02B\xbf1\x05z\xbfP\xf6\x1e\xbe\xdc(\x06\xbf\xcde\x0f\xbd\xf4B\x1e\xbe\xa3QJ\xbd\x04Z\x06\xbf\x03L\x00>b\xbf\xa3>\x026\xf0>\xfe(0>\xc5\xfe_\xbe\xae\x05/\xbf\xd8F\xc5\xbb\x05\xf1\xad\xbe\xb4x\xfe\xbe\xbf\xfe\xe3=\xd6\x9a*\xbfin<>\x90#!>\x04i3\xbf\x8c;-\xbf\x95\x8e\x13\xbf/\xf1j=H\xb7\xd4=\x1d\n\xfe>`\xa1\x0e\xbf\x1f\x8f\xd7=\xd0C\xfd=\xb3G.\xbe\xef\xc3\xf4>\n{\x0c>\x9d\xff\x10?l\xa2\x8b>iG\x18\xbfKE\x81>\x94\xd0\xa5\xbei\xdc\xfbBw\x8f\xfdB\xb7@\xfdB\xd8\xc9~C\xb0\xb8}Cp\xd9|C\x8c<6C\xa2\xe75CG\xec5C@\x11I>j\xe7\xec=\xd5\x87;\xbf%7\x9f>\xebG\xb5\xbd\xbf<\x1f\xbf/\x98\x1b>\xeaj\xd4>\x0c\xa6\x16\xbe\xb1\xb2\xf3>L\xc9\xb2\xbe\xf6"\x08\xbe\xad\xe4\xe1\xbe\xd2\x1eY?\xe9\xbb(\xbfQ\xce\xf5\xbe\xf4<\x9d\xbeSq\xb9>\xbb\x1d\xb8>\xd3\xad\x01?@\x89\xac\xbe~-\xa0\xbe\x99\xa7\x80>\x9f*\x9c\xbe\xaf6\xff>E\xbe\\?\xcb\xb7\x0c\xbf#!\xc7\xbe)4\x94=\xda)T\xbfe\x7fk\xbe\x94\x00\x15?\x8e\xd2J\xbb\n\xe2\x03\xbfV\xcb\xa5>\x8d\r\x15>\xdci\x16\xbf\x10\xff\xd9\xbe\xf8.~?\xbc\xbc\xb2>\xdd\x06\xca\xbe\xef\xf62\xbf^\xfc\x04\xbfwY">~\x90\x98\xbe|\xdf\xde\xbem&2\xbfx\xac\x8e?\x80\x99\xdf=Wm\xec\xbcm\xdb\xa5\xbe\r\xfe\xdb>\\\x1cg\xbed\x9c\xbe\xbe<\x9b\xaa=q\xa9W?\xd5\x91\x12?"$\xbb\xbaH\xd7\x1e>\xc6N\x97\xbe\xaa\x8d\x8a\xbf\xa5\xff\x06\xbf\xe9u\xd5\xbe\x1f\xa1*>\rr\x1f\xbf\xfdG\x15\xbf\xd6\xfd\x0e\xbe/,\xe7>\xa4NU\xbe]\x99j=\xd0Lq\xbdk0\xa2\xbf\x97\xeb\x95B\xfe\xdb\x95B}!\x95B\xecjzC\xe8\xc7yC\xf6\xeczC\xfcbpC\xa8{pC\xa8\x05pC4\'aB\'\x03bB\n\x9eeB}2\x01?\x14H\x8f>\xf5U*?K|7>\xefx1\xbf\xd2\x1b\x9a?WL\x8a\xbf\xfb\n\xc2\xbe\\\xb4\xa5\xbd\xe1\xdc\xd3\xbd\xf9\xcf\xc3\xbc\xfc\xda5>%\xd4\x02\xbf\xf8\x7fy\xbb\xa2-\xe1>\xc1\xbdP\xbf)\x8c6?Z\xd6\x08?\xd1\xe2X\xbeJ\x00\xd9\xbf\xefo,?\xff\xb5\xa9>]\x92\x02\xbe\x8b\xb8\xfa\xbd\x03\xc1\xdd>\xfa\x04\xb6>\xce7\x06>\t4\x06\xbf\xaf\xea\xd2\xbd?1\x04\xbe\xfa\xcb\xfa=\xfc\xd8\x86>\x84\x96\x85\xbe\xe1\xc2i\xbf\xd4\x06J\xbeK\x0f\x0e?*-\x9d>H\x02\x03?n\xf9\xa0\xbd\xd9\xea\x18\xbe\xb0\xd5\x15=\x1b\x87\x08\xbf\xaa\x0cE?\xa8b\x9a\xbd\xa2n\\\xbf\xc6\x82)\xbf\x18\x1e\x89\xbf1lN?\xd8\xa1\xc4\xbe\xb5\x90\xe7\xbe\x86P??9\xfd\xa4=c\xcaH\xbfb\x04#\xbe\xfd\xfb`?\x16\xd7#=\xeb\x9c\xad?\xdeD\xef>\x1e\t\xd0\xbel\x99\xb6\xbd\xd5\x92\xc7\xbe\x9b\x81?>\xd1\x9c\x01?\xaaj\xab>\xf4\xa8N>;\xf6F= s%\xbf\x7f\xf0\x91>wW\\\xbf\xd1D\x92A\xec\xef\x98AC\xfc\x9cA\xf8\x9b\\C\xdb*]Ck\x1f]C\xe9;~C]Y~C\xef*~C\xd0\xee%C\x04u%C\x1f-&C\xba\x08\x86>\xd8\xb5\x07?\xc2\x17\x93\xbe<\xaf\xaa?(\x8f\x9a\xbe\xdeFP>ww\x11\xbfo\xe2J\xbd\x7f\x14\xb8\xbd\xc7.0\xbf\xb1\xbf2>|\xd2e\xbf\x9d\x0c\xa5?_\x11\x11\xbf2m\xc2\xbea\xcc5=?R\x81\xbf\xa7\x9f\x97?\xfd\xae\xe5\xbe\x82\xbd\xe6\xbe\x86\tA\xbe\x9eP\x8a\xbfJey=TY\x08>\x11\xaa\xa9\xbf\xc5\xb9^\xbe\x97\x8c2\xbf\xbc(\xd4\xbe\x90(W\xbcU\xcc\xed>=\x1bh\xbe\xe6\xf36\xbe \xe3e\xbf\xea\x8e??T*\xa2?\x81\xb8c?\xa5"\xd3>a\xa3\xe0>\xdc\x15\x8b\xbe\x04P\x15\xbf\x8b\x1bV>{\xa9:\xbd\x10(w>\xc8\x9a1?a\x06}>\xb8\xfb\x14\xbe\xa9S\x06?\xb5\xb4\xba>\x03\xaf\xed\xbe\x05)\xfb>_\xa1\x84>l\x85\x12>\xbfpv\xbf\x90u:\xbe^c9\xbf\xeb\xb1\x82?\xe0\x9f\x0f\xbf\xa1;\x1a\xbfP\xa3\xc6>\x08\xa0\xbe<\x82\xc0\x94\xbd%\xdeJ\xbf\xc3\xd3\x03?\xdb\xa7 >\xee\x01\xf2\xbdw\xed\x08\xbf\xd6XP?f\'\x0b\xbe2\x05\xde\xbe\x0b\\@@\x19]\x1c@\xa3ZE@\xb3bJC\xc0{JC\xab\xe4JC\x1b\xea}CuK}C\xee\x93}C\xc5\xa4ZCC\x8a[C\xf7\xabZC\x8f\x04\nB\x91y\rB\x9e\xf7\x0cB\x9d\x19\xdd>\xf4\xbc\t?\x83\xfd\xf3>Z\x07\xe9\xbe e\xd7>\xe0\xf2\xbf>\xbc\xb2{\xbf\x07}\xf0\xbc\xc0\x1fI>\xcc\x12\x04?{yd=qY\xa6\xbe\xad7C>\x84\xc1\x82=\xbbn\xd9\xbe\xc0\x84,?\xe3\x12\xa2\xbe\x8a\x81(?\x06\xccH\xbe\xec\x95T>\xcb\x13\x8b\xbe\xb5I\xe9\xbe&_\x02>\xafq\x04?\xad\xbe\xfb\xbd\xbaiU?\xbe\xca\x16\xbfJ^F\xbf>6\x89>\xd8\xac\'\xbf\xcaJ\xe9>I_\x8f>\xa2)\x8b?f.D>\xf2"\xde>LD\xca=(Ox\xbdD\xf7v=\xec\x01;\xbf\x1c!l>\x92\x98">d\xdcM\xbe:\xfcF\xbf\xd0I\x82>|\x0b\xcd\xbd\xd3W\x0b?b{\xac\xbct5\x0b?\xc5\xc9?\xbe\x8fh\x91?\x93\xdc\xcf\xbe\x8by\xee\xbd\xcc %?\xca\xc6\xd0>\x8c\x92\xec\xbck\x8d\x85\xbf\x0bt\x9b\xbf\x92Z0\xbf\x1fW\x1a?\xfd\x904?P`.>\xa0\x84\xb1>t\xe0\xaa=|\xa5\xfa\xbe>zC?\xca\xf4\x01\xbf\x00\x0e\xc5\xbd\xb9\xcb\xeb\xbe\xd7Gt?\xf4\xff\x17B\xbe\x12\x17B\xfc\xe8\x19B\x18\x18~C\x1b1~C:T}C\x9c\xf7}C\xfa\x0e~C\xaa\xc2}C\xa4H\x99B\x15\xf4\x9bB\xdcq\x97B\xfbWh=r< \xbfDQi>\xfd\xf6\x02\xbf\x10&\xbb>\xb5\x90\xff>\xab\xf2Y\xbfg<9\xbeh\xc6]?S\xe2\xa5>s\x7f\x95>\x18^F\xbf\xcd\x8ac>\xf9\x87s>\xf3\xaf\xac>\xed\x18\xc2>m\x7f\x04?y\xf8i>\xaa\x93<\xbe/\x9d\x04\xbfS\x17\x8b>\x88\r\x9b>\x18\xc4Q?V\x1c,?W\\\x1e?yW\xb9\xbe`.m>\x1e?&\xbf\xe2\xff/>\xa8\x88\xe1=\xd8\xaa\x82>\xc4\xce\xc1\xbe\xed\x0c%\xbf7\x14b>\xac\xb3\x1e?\x87j\xb9\xbf\xb1\xf3\xba>\xdf=%\xbf\x003:?(\xc9\t\xbfD\x17\xc4\xbdt\xf2\n?\xce\x19\xd6=+\xc0\x8c>\xf3mL?\xde\xef\x9b?@\x87\x9d>\xe4\xf7\xc3\xbe4\xe2\x9e\xbe\x97\xfb\x01?\xb76\x9b\xbd\xc1\xb8\x0e?\xb5(\xd6>\xf3\xa3\xa8\xbe}$\x9d>\xd3\x1e6?\xc4H\x8e\xbe\xa10\x9b>`\x10#?\xf2i\xf4\xbeX\xf6\xe0=^L\x14\xbftX\x04\xbf\x8e\x17\xb7>\xe3\xa0\xc8>o\x8e~\xbd;&??\xe3\xa6A?u\xa61\xbeG\xde\xfaA\xb2\xf6\xf6A\xed\x03\xf0A\xfb\x93_CE\x02`Co\xa1`C)\xc8}C\x1bx}C\x11\xed}C\xf9\xe2\xe4B\x06\xa4\xe4B\xd7\xdd\xe6B\x9a\xce\xcd?\xda\\\x88?\x8f[\x8f?Wx\x16?Q!\x11\xbe\x8b\x0b=?\x13)\xf9:\xb9\x04\x9a\xbf\xf1\xcf\xcb\xbe\xb2\xca\x8f\xbf\xa7\xa1\x87>\xfb\xaa\x1c\xbfxU0\xbf\xf7\xfd\xa9<\xab\x03\xab==\x91F>\x13\xdcB\xbf\x80\x1b\xda>\xf7\xd55\xbeN\xca\x8b<\xf5i\x1a>:-L\xbe\x9f\n\xe4\xbdZ\xce\x89\xbe\x99P\x91>\xc9\x10 \xbf\xb9Oh>\x856\x02?\xf5\xa3\x0e<V\xa3\xab\xbde\xc2$>\xe1Ye?;\xfe\x93\xbd\xdf~\xfe=]\x18\xa5\xbe\xd0\t\xe1<\x9e:\x0e?K\x1a\xab?\xe0\x95O?\xf4\xb9\x1d>\xc5\xd4\xda=[Q@\xbf7`1>_9\xec\xbd\x1a\x1e\x1c\xbf\xe4\xd7\xf7\xbe\xf0#\x17\xbdY%\xa0=\xdd\xf8\x1a\xbf:B\xf8\xbd\xcd*\x8f>h\xc6x>x6\xf6=\xc1\x0c\xa6\xbf\xea\nw\xbf\x8d\xa4K\xbf\xcf\xc8\x7f\xbezH#\xbf\xe5\xf0S>$\xc5\x04\xbf\x97\x8fF\xbe\x0b\\\x95\xbeh\xc8\x89\xbf\xa0W\x1c?\x9c!\x92?<\x1c\xc4>\xc5\x13\x14>\xa3nE\xbd4\x01\xa9>A\x82\x84\xbf \x0b\xac\xbf\x1a\xf0\x9d>\xe5\x03\x05Ck\x08\x04C\x8aC\x05C\xc2\x9e}C2h}C\x1d)~CS\t~C\xa4b~Cf\xa8}C\x81mOB\x16EOBF\xc0QBs\xf9r\xbfo\x8aP\xbf\xb4\x80\xca>Y\xa2\xc0>L\x176\xbf\x98T$\xbf\xbc,\x95?G\xe4M>D\xd0\xa4\xbd\xb7\xb5\x16?G\x08B?X\xfdI>\x8e\x0e\x9a>\xeb\x93\t>\xe9\xfe\x9c>t\x8cM?RS\xa6>4\x15@=\xf2N\xc0\xbe\xc4|\x1f>E\xe4\x80\xbd|@\xf2>\x97\xb11\xbeY\xcd&\xbf\xe8j\xf0\xbeYG8>\xc4\x1a\x11\xbeY\xe0m\xbf\xf3?\x06\xbe\xf4\xbe\x9c>-\x88Z\xbek\xd0\xfd\xbeD\xed\x8c\xbd\xa8\x92\x0c?\xd4\\\x1b>F\xbe\n\xbf]\xaf+?x\xd7\x16\xbe\x81-\x03?\xd79\xb2\xbd\x95\xdf\xa6>\xe0\xe26?B\xbb"\xbf!\x11\xf5>\x87\xfa\x0f\xbf\xe4\xced>\x92h\xe9>\x8a\xac\x13\xbf\x9c\xe5@\xbeFJ\x1e\xbf\xf1#\xaf>\xbc\x1f\xa7?\x9e\xc2\xa1\xbe\n\xb1\xac>~\x94\xa0\xbei\xef\x17?\x1c\x9b\x94?k\xef\xdb>\xb3\xfb\x93\xbfT\xfa\x89\xbe\xd1\xe8z?\xc6\xac\x1f\xbf&\xb8\xcc\xbe\xa1|\x00?\xab\xc9\x16?\xb2\x00\xbb>\x9a\x10\xe4=\xeb\x85\xd1\xbe\xaa\x12\xae\xbe\xc2\xc4rB\\8pB\x04nuB}\x89qCj\xb4qC{\xb5qC\x97$~C\x92g~C9\x87}C\x0b\\~C\x8a\xc3}C\xee\xd3}C\xbd/RB\xde\xc0PB\xcfGNBf\xc4W?[L\xa3>\xf5\x84\xc5\xbe\x07\x07\xf4>\xb5\x9b\x8d\xbe\x9dG\xde\xbe\xb2\x05\x85>\x02\xe0\xa7>V\x91\x93>\xc5\xfb\xbb\xbe\x15\xd4\xcf>$\x91\xf3=\x17\x94C??F$\xbfa"\x11?_\x01\x00>0\x1f\x82\xbfC\x02o>\x9a\\H\xbf(\xcfZ\xbf)B\x97\xbcjk\x91>\xaf\x9c\xb5\xbe\x8a\x1aF?""N>5Zw>\x83\xb91?1\xecO>\x8b\xfa\xee>\x9d\xef\x9e=\xf0\xc4\xe9\xbe\xa5\x04\xe0<\xd9\xca\xb0?\xabs\xed\xbe\xad\x12\x80=\x06\x9d\x02\xbf\\\n&\xbf}\xd2\xae\xbe\xcd\xfeC?\x10i\x9d>(\xafm?>#\x9c=\xe4\xd8\x92=\xdb9\xdc\xbeI\x11\x97>\x15\t\xd3=\x9e2\x1d?)c\xfb>\xef`\xab>\xc7\x85\xe4\xbe\xeb-\x0c\xbe\x91\xbe\xda>\\\xdf\x9e?\xcb\xafl\xbeN\xd2\x83\xbe\x8a\xb2:\xbevA\x8b\xbdrJh\xbe\x95\xe1\xd4\xbe\xa4r\x80?\xd7\xbe\x01\xbf$^u>\xbf\x1b6?\x8bi.?n\xd3\x93>\xe34\x12\xbdT(\x02?\xd2\xcd\xdc>\xb4t;>uJ\xf2B\x0b\x87\xf2B\xec\x90\xf1B\x1b\x18~CW|~C`\x8c}C^\x1e~CD~~C\xbaN~C\x8e)[C\xcc\x04[C\xf9\xb8[C\x9aG\x1fB\xc0\xa4 BI\'!Bd\xf3A\xbfm.\xd6\xbe\x13\x05\xc9\xbe\xe5\xb4\xeb\xbd\xe63\xeb\xbd#\x9c\x04\xbe\xdc\xa2\x06\xbf\tc\x02?\xda%o>\x92\x18S\xbf\x8dD\x8b?\x0e\x8f\xbe=@_*?\xd6\x12C?w+\x91=\xdf\xf3A?\xbd\xc4\x1c?\xcf\xa7\x1d?v\xbdA?\x07\x9b\xa1\xbc\x99\xca\xa9>\xacA\xfe\xbb.\x8aK\xbe\xda \xee>Q\xe2g<\x0br\x13?&\x8b|\xbd\x80\x9a,?\x03\xd7->`\xd3\xa1\xbd\xa3g[\xbe\xdf\x99\xe9<?\xe2\x06=?{\x04\xbe\xe1\xe7\x16?\xfeU\x11=\\\xc1O?H\xda\xf8\xbe\xe3\xfeu\xbd\xd5\xdf\x19\xbe\'w\xa7>{H \xbeN_1>\x8b\xe3\x8e=\xfdE\xe8>\xff\x173\xbd\xda\x07&\xbf\\ B=\xb3\xb2t\xbeh\x0cg\xbf\x8cw\xeb\xbc\x85\xa1\x18>\xe0\x0c\n?F\xdbL>\x02\xe3\x00?R\xe7\x0b\xbf\xb9\xcc\x08>,\x00<\xbd\xcd\x87\n?\x1a\xec\x90\xbeL&}9\x95\t\xd6\xbd)\x1a\xb0=\x0c\xf1\x87?\n\xd0;\xbfB`\xa4?\x8f\xd5\xd1\xbe~\x14r?L\xc7b>\xc5a\xf0B\xf7y\xf1B\xf13\xf3B\xae!~C\xfb\x0e\x7fC\x91=}C0INCK*NC\xc6\x8eNC\xaa\n\x91A\xeb\x01\x91Aor\x8bA\xbf\x0e.>3\x93D>U"->\xe7\xed\xd4>\xb1\xed\x8f\xbe\x07\x865?f\x85\xfe\xbey\xbe\x03?m\xbd\xd7=\\Z\x01?]z\xc6\xbe\x9ag\x81\xbfa\xa2:\xbe\xd1\x0c\x86\xbe\xdeu\xaa>~\x89\x8c?m{\x8a?\xad\xbb\x97\xbf@\x9d\xda>\xe9\x15\x86\xbeY\x80*\xbf\x8fd<\xbfH~9?\x1b\x81e?E\xac\xfd=\x08\xc32>\x86\x95\xb9\xbe\xb5\xcc%?\xc5s\'\xbd\xeb\xf1\xc2\xbe\x92\xab\x18?\x1e\x9a\xfe>p\x1d\xa8?Y"\x1a\xbd\xce\xd5{=0K]\xbf\xa2?\xe3>\x02\xba\xe6\xbeV\xe2\x94?\x1d\xe3\xfc>\xea\x9cg\xbe\xba\xb4R?\xa5q\x1e\xbf\xff\xf47\xbf\xf5\x80F>\xbclA\xbb\xe5\x14\x11\xbf\xd7y\xec\xbey3\x0f?\x86\x91\xc6=\xe8\x96~>\xf3d\x16\xbf1v\xd0>\xdd\xa1$>k\xa5 >\xf9k\x82>\xc1\xbf\x9f>\n\x94y<\x96_6?\xbb\x8b\xe5>\xa8N{>\xd4\xfd\t?\x1f\x1f6\xbe\x99\xd5\xd0;G\xc9\xde=nSa>\x9d\x00N?5z\x0c?-xJ>\xb5P\x08?\xa3\xed\x9a\xbe\xf7\xdc\x04\xbf.,#\xbe\xc3l%?l\x95R>2\x1a\xc1\xbd5=\xde\xbd\xf8\xecE>X\xfd\x89\xbe\x1d4\xaa\xbd\xe3\x9ag>vT\xbc:/s\xe3>\x17\xe0C?\x8d\x8f=\xbf<\\2=\xfbA?\xbf\x0cG\xf5=\xdb\x80\x12>\xbb\xad\x00\xbf\xea\x96C\xbfq\xa8\xf8>\xde\x84\xbb\xbeq\x19F\xbe\xe6\xbbw?_H\x1b\xbf(\xbe\x87\xbe%\xa1\xfe\xbaW\xc3Q\xbe%\x87D?\n\x8a]\xbe.P\xa0\xbe/u\xce?\x87&\x92>h\xb7\xf9>md"\xbc\x1d\xc6\x85\xbeG\x1a:?\xa0\xbc\x8c\xbe\xa8\xd8)>\xbd\xfb\xdf>\xaa;4\xbe!E\xf0\xbe\x90Ql>\x075\xdc?\\\xf9$\xbf*M\x83\xbe\xa9\xb6R=;\xb5\x94>\xec\xdd\x07>\xc6C\xcf\xbd\xf3fE\xbe!A\x8b\xbc\xe2\x18\xa1\xbe\xff\x89\x1a?tN\x8f>'
test_bytes = bytes(test_bytes)

test_image = np.frombuffer(bytes(test_bytes), dtype=np.float32).reshape(28, 28, 3)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(test_image)
plt.title("test_image")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(~test_image)
plt.title("test_image - invert")

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Here is the error:**

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_28462/820192811.py in <cell line: 17>()
     15 
     16 plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
---> 17 plt.imshow(~test_image)
     18 plt.title("test_image - invert")
     19 

TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

How to `invert` this test image with "`~`" operator?

And how to fix this error in this image:

```
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

Comment: You provide the image as `float32` data type. This data type does not support inversion via the `~` operator. Also, for float data, the values must be in the range `[0, ... ,1]` which doesn't seem to be the case for your image; hence, the values get clipped.

Comment: How can I convert the float data to the range of `[0, ..., 1]`? And how to invert with other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rescale your data from the -1.695 ... 255.408 to the range of 0 ... 255. Due to floating point operations, you still need to [`clip`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) the rescaled image to the range of exactly 0 ... 255. After converting to integers inverting is just doing `255 - image`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test_bytes = b'\x8bE\xd4=\xacF\xdc\xbd\xfc\x02\x1f>=\r\xba\xbd\x0c\x9a\xbd>\x11tP>E,\x10?\x9d(\x03?\xb0\x18\xfa\xbd-$\xd4=#P\\=k\xe9}?\xac\r\x93\xbe\x87\xe1\xfd>\xff0e=C\xdf-\xbcCc\xe4\xbd?ff\xbf\x989\xbf\xbe5\x8ag\xbf\xaa_\x14?\xb7\xd6;\xbe\x9c*`\xbe\xf12\xe2=U\xc5l>)7\xa3>F^\xea\xbe\xc0\\8<\xc5\xb2\x03?\x9c\x8e\x1a\xbf\xe5lV:\x8b\xbf\x98>\x9e\xc5Y\xbf\x93\xec\xe2>e\xd0\x81\xbe\xf8\x94[>\x01S5=\xdb\xab\xb8>\xef\x05\xb6\xbd.\xaaS\xbf\xfaS\xa2\xbe\x14\x0f0\xbe\xed\xaf\x8c>/\xdc\x86\xbf\xb8\x8e\xbb>*\x97\xed\xbeS@\x0f;$c\x82\xbe_\xd5\xb2\xbe)\xa6\xa1=\xe9\xe9\x04\xbe9J\x9a?\x99\xbf\x02>\xcaA\x8d>C\xe73?\xbbgI>\x93\xf8\xea>\x92\xbd\x10?A\x85\x93\xbf\x18Q&?;\x80V\xbe\xe6\xaa;\xbf\x07\x02\xae>C1\x89>F\x12\xb5>\x90\xf6\xbe\xbc\xb2\xf4\x95\xbeo\x0e\xae\xbe\x97\xdfV=\xef\xeb\xe2\xbdNc0\xbf@zx\xbfv\x86Y?\x1c\xc7l\xbf\xe7\x0ed?\x19Wk\xbf\xcb_.\xbd\x17\xdd\xb7=\xb7\xfc\xe1\xbd \x07\xb9=\xaa\xa3\xd3>t\x8f6\xbe\x7fWC>\xa6\x07\x11?iN\x9d\xbd\xa2g\x1d?\xef\xff\x16?\x9b\xde\xf3\xbc\xbdn\x14\xbf\xfe\x9dL\xbe\xb3W0>\x8fqJ\xbf\xcd\xb8\x9e<\xc6\n\xdf\xbeU\x18\x8b>\x1e\xf8\x9c>\x84&\xb9\xbdK\x13`\xbel\xd0B>\x88\xb6\x8e>\xb8`\xa2>2#\\\xbf\xb7\xdb\xaf=\x91\x12\x93>\xbf\xcc.\xbf\xfd\x88\xe3\xbe\xc9\xab\xe6=|`a?3\xfb\x94>\x9d\xb9\x0e?>\xf0\xab>o\xf3\x9e\xbe,\xb3\x11?`V\x1a\xbf\x849\xa8>\xca\x04}?\x96{\xb5=\x0f\x80\xa5>\'o\xef<\x99\xd9\x81\xbe \xed\xa2>\xa3j<?&a~?\xe8R\x05=\xce\xea\xb1\xbef8`>\xc5 \x05\xbf\xb0\xc6\x83\xbeY\x88\x0f\xbfC\xff}\xbeU\xc3\x11>0\x18>\xbf\xbe\x82\'\xbf4\xe9\x93\xbe\x84\xc0\xa7>\xfb\xf6\x8d\xbeI\xbe\xb8\xbd\xd2\x964\xbe\xa5L\xa0\xbe\x93\x1d\x9c\xbe\xac\xea\xb8\xbd\xd5\xf5y?6\x81>?\x01I\xae>\xdc\xd8\x11\xbfHW\x1e?\xdc_\x87\xbe\xd3\x17"?`w\xb3\xbc\xa053>,P8=P\xb50>\x8b\xc4\xba>\t\xbc%\xbe\x13Q\x82>\xba.\x9e=\xc5f\n\xbe\xd9\xc9\xed=\xf7\xf0+?n\x1f\xe5>7\xd1\xdb>\xea\xef"\xbe\xd1/3?x\x15*?.\xdcO>3\x99\x90=8&\xa0?\x9b\xdc#>:>\xd4>\xa3\x9f\xd0\xbe\x16\xc6&?\'@|\xbf\x18\x05\xf2=\x08\xc4~>\x87XY>\xd8=\x19\xbe2\xeb,?-\x08\xaa\xbde\x93\n>n[\xce\xbem\xe0\xa2\xbe\xfe\x1e\xa0>(\xd6?>\xfe\xf9\x14?\xea\x0e\xc9\xbeh\x0c\x94?\xd1m\xc4\xbfS\x0c3\xbe\xb3\x9e@>\xb5`\x82\xbe\x8e\x8b\xd4>\x1c\xa4\xad>\x96(\xfc\xbbp;P>\xb0\xc6\xb2>R\xeb\xc3\xbe\tj\xdd>x\x95!\xbf*\xaa\x1a\xbf\xb8\xa7~>z\xdc\x13?\xcf\xd3Y\xbf\xe5\xcd\x0b>\x95\x12\xfb\xbek\xa5m\xbeB\xbd\x14?\xe6p_>\xe6\xcb\x9b\xbee\xc1&?U\x9d\xb0\xbfjL@?\xc0-N>\x11\x9d \xbcU\xdf@?\xaex%>\xee{\x08?\xa2\xc3k\xbf<\xed\xe5\xbc{T\x96\xbc0"*>w6%\xbfPh\r\xbe\x12y:\xbf\xdd\xaa\xdd=\x17t >\xb4c\xfd==\x84\x10\xbfl\'\x0c\xbd\x9a\x0f\x1d\xbe\xb2\x03\xec\xbe\xf0\xa6\xa3>\xe2d\x00>h\xb8\xfd\xbd7\xac\xa1>J\xa7\xfa=\xe9\xab\x9e>l\xb7/\xbe\xa3`\x05?\xa9\x1e\x85?\x05\x05*?"\xec\xb4>\x0c\xe8\xee>\xbc\xbaS?i\x16d\xbd\xba\xed3>\xd8S[>\x1d\x7f\x94?\x084\xe0\xbd+\n\xb4\xbe\x89HG\xbf\xf1\x93\x0f?\x987\n\xbf\\\x8fs?\xf6\xbe ?\xa8\xca\xf3=\x84\x07U\xberJ\x92\xbe\xc0\xad\xac>\x12MY\xbf\x12{\xf4\xbe\xbc\xc6.?\x9f%\xd8\xbe\xa8\xaaL>y\x99\x95>\x8f\xc0\x07?\xa5\x84\x89\xbe\xd6\xb1\xa3\xbeT\xec\x0c?\xddZ\x88>\xf5\xd3*\xbe\xc1\xa3\xbd\xbd\x853\x91\xbe\xca\x0c\x14>\x11\x18x\xbe:q]\xbf\xfc\xb1\x82\xbf ;\xe6>\xdc;\xcc\xbd\xe9X\x05\xbf\xcf\xcd\xb9\xbfe]t>\xf0\x84\xc1?\x8c\xffM\xbe\xc8\xb5 >\xa5\x9d\xdd=\xe8c\r\xbf\x89\xd8\x1f>\xaf\xe8P\xbfI\\\x83\xbdGH\xe3\xbe\\3\xbf>\xa2\x1b\xd5>\x0c\x1a\x04?\x18\x17\xad?\xf0\r\xc6>\xa2\xc2\x9f\xbd\xe9M\x80?\xa62\x95\xbd9H\xb9>w,\x1a\xbe\xb0ch?\x89"m>\x8ex\x12=\xc2[Z=\xc2\xa3\xc3\xbf\x86dB>\xff\xee\x1e\xbfi\xa4\x9e>(P9\xbe\xa5\xf0\x1d?=\x17U\xbe\xe9\x0e\x18=\xea\xb6\xaf>\xb8t\'\xbe\xca\xbe[\xbf\x7f\xd9\x8f="\x9aL\xbe\xa4\x10?>2\xa2\x9b\xbeb\xbcR\xbd\x15^\x9a=)\xb8\xe7\xbdJg\x03?\xe6\xf6g>#\xde#\xbe\xca\x92\x19\xbe\x8d\x95\\\xbe\x97I\x12\xbe\x9eF\x03\xbf\xc04\xbf=u\xa9\xe9\xbe+\x1b\xb1>\xff\x8bB\xbd\x16V\xde\xbe\x82\x8b\xe4\xbe\xb0\xb8\x88>\x19\xb3\x9b\xbc\x8f\x82\x90\xbc\x7f\x14\xc2=G{\xe5>\x90\x1b\xbd=\xcf\x14c\xbf\t\xf7O>\xe2\xbc_>\x1e"G\xbd\x14]@>\x15G\xce\xbe2\x8a\xa7\xbe\x9b\x033?\x9f\x11G\xbfT\x0e\xbf\xbe\xe2\xc5\xf9>\xb9\xcd\xd5\xbc\xd6#\x96>\x83W\r<!U6>\xe2\xcd\xfa=E\x80\x81\xbe\xa8\xaa\x83\xbdk=B>^\x03\x89>E\xeb\x13\xbe\x07\x8c\x8f?\xbe\xbb\x12\xbe\x9c.\xaa\xbeY\xd6\x04=\xd9\x8c\xa7>7s\'>\xc0\x18\xb0\xbe\xe0)z?\xa1^\xad>1\x96\x8d\xbea\x8c\xba>\r\x04\xb1>\xdf\xa4C\xbf\x05AS?\x07+\r>\xb7L\xa2\xbfw\x83&?\x9e]Y\xbf[+\x15=\x84\xfb\x0b\xbe\xda\x12\xe3>\x9b:e?\x82\x07=\xbe\xe7{\xcd>\xb2\xbae>\xa0Jj\xbf\x86Y_\xbf\xdb\xd58>:a\xcf=\xe7[\x13\xbe\\\x18*\xbfFE\xd1\xbe\x91\xfe\xa9>\xd1\x006\xbfX\x1f:?\xc7\xfd\x87\xbeR\xf3\n\xbf\t5.?\xe4\xe0!?^\xd8.\xbf0\x0c\xb2\xbeK\xf06?I \xab\xbd\xcd\xf7\x15?\xeat\x97\xbe`_\xc9>\r\x88i=\xa5v\x0f?\x91\xe9\xa3\xbeYB\xdb>\xebG6?\xcd\xb2\x06?\x9f\xc7\xc3>\xb7Qg=A\xff\x10\xbf\\^\xc6\xbe\xbd\x83\x11\xbf\x8b;\xee\xbc\xe9c\x88\xbe+V\x92?\x06\xc2p>\xa1\x87\x15\xbfr*\xff\xbe\t\xd5\x98>\x8b\xee+\xbe&H_?\xa6\x009>\xd6\x039\xbf0\x85\x16?\x9d\xd1\x90\xbdDl\x99\xbe\xa5.\xa1>\xa39Y\xbe|\x87\xa5\xbe?r\xb8\xbc\xf2c.>#H"\xbf\xde\\\x89<\x08\x85n\xbe\xe7\xe3\x1e\xbfG\xfc\xad\xbe\xcf\xfc\xfb>\xc8a\xd5\xbe|!\xc8>|5W\xbe\x85\x91\x04\xbf\xaa\x15a\xbeN\x7f\xae\xbe\xe4)=\xbe\x97\x02w<S\x0c\x11=\xdfh\x8a\xbe\xaa\x92\xb4>\xc2\xac\xdd=\xe5\xe1\x1b?\xed\n]>\xf75f\xbf\xc5d\xa4\xbeF\x1f\x9e\xbf\x06\xd8)>\x9c\x7fQ\xbf\xee\x95-?\x94Mv=\xc5\xa8\xff=\x04\xc0\xd4\xbcm\x88\xb3\xbe\x02a^\xbfG<\xa4\xbe+\x16\x8b\xbepl\x83\xbd\x99\x9a\xb4>\xd3t\x02>\x85\x00\xb0=\x89\xcc\xb6=\r\x03\xbd>[\xa4\xc1>\x81\xb6g\xbes")?\x92\xce\x1b\xbe(9 >+\x02u\xbeK,\x10\xbfr\xf6s\xbfe\x96\xed\xbe\xc4\xb3Q\xbdE-a>\x08A\x86?\xa3\x92\x82=\xae\xdf\xb2\xbd\x1f\xea\x0b\xbf\x07\xcb>\xbf)\xf6\xeb>\xf2o\x07\xbeZ4\x85?\x9fN\x8a\xbef\xb6\xb0\xbcy\x12{\xbd%\x0e\xba\xbe\xcd"&>\x1d\xff>\xbf\xc3P\x8c<G\xbf\xb4=\xbd7\x9a\xbe\xe6\xc1\x89>c\xecY?C\xc5\x80=XHD\xbf\xfe\xef\xf6\xbe\xc9\x95\xa4\xbd\xa0\xef\xd4>R\x9a\xb5\xbeVz\xb4>\xb6\x94\xe3\xbc+\xad\xc6>\'\xa5\xd5\xbe\xab\x90\xbb\xbe\xc2%d>\xcc|-?B\x96,\xbe\xa4J\xa5>\x92j\x8e\xbdZ\xb2\x8b?A@\x88?\xc5\xdf\x8e>\xef\x1dH=\xb9\x8e\x13>\xdbK\xcd>\xe2n\x96>\xef(t\xbe\xb0\x7f\r?\\\xa8\xe3>\xedz\x0c\xbf\xa5a\xa3\xbe\xc2\xb4\x80>W1-\xbeD\xb5]>\xad,\x8f>m\x00\x17?XX"\xbe\x8c\xaf\x04\xbf\xe6\xd0\x1a\xbe\xd8\xbb\xeb=\xfe_\xb7<\xff\x12\xcf>;\x9bs>\xd4\xb5\x12\xbe&\xc8\xb7\xbed\xcb\xd2\xbd\xcfb"=\xee.\xf6\xbe\x01\xb5\xf7>:I\xa7\xbd\xb1\x93\x01\xbd\xad4\xe1>\x94\xcb\x88\xbd]\x9d\x80\xbf1\xac\xb9<q\xccL\xbeUsv\xbe\x8a\x9b\xc6\xbc\xa2U5\xbf\xc7\xdb\x1b?,\xd1\x93>\xc7\xa5\x1b>\xaf\xba\x06>p\xb1P?h\xb8\x01=\xee6\x0b\xbf&`)>!\x11\x11?\x9a\xd51?PG\x86>\r\x9bz?\xf6\x81\xdb>!\xc8\xa4>L\x96j>.\x0b\x91>\x94\xec!>\xef4\xcd\xbe\xdf3??\x1a\xff\xa2\xbe|[\x8f>\xac)\xa8\xbe\x89H\x8a?\x85"\x05\xbf\xf7[\xa7>.\xeeW?\x91\xf2\x90>\xa9\x1a\xb2=0\xf1\xe5\xbeG\xbf\x8c\xb9NH\x96?,)\x8f>\x0f\xb1\xd6\xbe4-9>1pH?\x1c\xbd\xe6>!\x82->\xfe\xa0\xf6\xbe\x01\xfd\xc5>\xd020\xbf\x98\xa8\xb3\xbf\xa3\xad\x14\xbd\xf6\xa08?\xcc\x0c\xa7B\xab\xd1\xa8B\xe4$\xa8B\xc4\x999C\xd3\xa69Coq9C\x19\xbf\x1fC\xeb\x8d\x1fC\xfc\'\x1eC\x16I\x17C-\xbd\x17Cn\x8b\x16C,\xbfoBl\xc8pBJ\xb0nBb\xbc\x12B\xb5\x00\x0eBF<\x11B\xa4g\xe4\xbe\xe1\x15V?\xfd\x00\xa5\xbe\xec\x8fb>R=\x04\xbf\xb7u\x98>L\xda\xcf=#\xfb\x1c\xbf\x1672\xbfp\xb6\xbd>\x06w\x91>\x8f\x0c\x87=\xeb\xd3n>\xc9\ri>\xc8+\xee=\xd7H\xb6=\x04\x01\xa6\xbd\xb7r!\xbf@#\xe3>oL\x04\xbfr\xe5?\xbee\x1f\x88=ZM\xe7\xbeg\xf1\x0c\xbf\xa9\xcd)?\xcf\xd5\x81\xbd\xb1\x0b\x19\xbf\x162j>[Q\x0e\xbe\xea\x8b\x94?\x15\xc9\x92>\x9f\xa0\xa8\xbe\x0f~\x10>\xda&\x8d=\xf3\x18\x93\xbf\xdf)\xd8>9@\x00?\xa2|m\xbe\xd3\x1fG\xbfE\x11l\xbd\xe1\x88\x0c?\xa7\xed\xa0\xbe\xdeY\x07>\xac3\x1a\xbe\xee\x1f\xff=$-H\xbeg\x04\x83=CP\xb5\xbe\x02\x06"<\x10j\x8a>\xdf7\xf3=\x1eTl>\\\x88K>P\xbf\x17\xbe\xcb2\x8c>\xf6v\xcc>k\xb8}>gnb\xbfK\x0f3\xbf<uI>>\x98\x90>+z\xe0>\xd5\xdfE\xbf\xcc\n2\xbe7\x1e\x02\xbf\xd3\x91{\xbd\x04*]C\x92\xc0]CMv^C\xd2`~C]\xfb}C\x81\xb4}C\x90\xf6}C\x89*\x7fC\xd1\xf8}C1Y~C\x95\x80}CO\x91~C\xf3"~CsF~C_\xeb}C\x0cCqC\xe8\xe6pC\t\xe3pC\xad\xe8EC<\xa9EC/XFC\x0e:FCK;FC\xcb\xc9EC\xcd}FC\x1a\xcbFC\xe9\x89EC\x0b\x06FC\xc3\x1aFCB\xc7EC\x01\xa2EC\x9ecFC\x12\xd5EC\xa9\xe6ECO>EC\x1f3FC 8FC\x1e\xd9EC\xefjFC\xd7\xfeFC\xe75EC\xc2:ECNx*Cm**Cc\x17*C\x03\xf1QB\x99\xceKB\xefyTB\x9d8\xc8\xbe\xa6\x9d~?\xcc\xf1\x93\xbe\xe5\xceJ>\x1cM\x83\xbb\xba\xdaF>VxC?Y1\x1b?\x94\x9e\xb6\xbd_MK>\xf7\x0b\x89>"\xe3\x07\xbf_*p>\xf5/\t>1\x92\x81\xbf2\xd1\x1b\xbd\xc9;m\xbf\x84\xe6I\xbd\xfc|\x8d?1\xc6h<o\x0b\x19\xbf\xf9\xee\xa4\xbe\x14I\xa8\xbeL7\'\xbfm\xb9\x9b=\xdd\'\x84\xbd\xaf\xa5\r\xbf\xb2\x80\xed\xbe\xb5\xc9\x0e>\x82\xe6\xe1\xbd\xb3\xa3\xdb\xbd)\x1f\x7f\xbfa6"?s\x11\xed>\x8dR.>Co\xea\xbd6\xd9\x85B\xcc\xe7\x86B\xd0\xf9\x85B\xcd\x94\xe6B\xbd\xb4\xe3B\xcav\xe5B\x82%\x90B\xb3\xff\x90BDS\x91B\xdfZ\xe3B\xf8\x80\xe2B\xc0\xa5\xe3B;\xd6"C\xe6\x99#C\xdb\x97#C\xafnbC0(cC\xa8\xfdbCD\xaf}C\x95\xf7~C\x1a\x85~CZ\x1faC\'F`C\xb7\x99`C\x129}C/\x08}C\xe2|~C[\xdd}C\xdf\xc4~C+\xae}C\x9a\x81}C\x9c}~C\x19\xe8~Cm|yC\xaf\x0bzC\x878yC\xab\xa8dC+\x1aeC{\xb7dC\xa9t~CA\xda}C\xef\xc8~C:\xdd~C\xaf\xee}CVc~Cyi\x0cC\x949\x0cC\x98\xf3\x0bCD(\x99>-#\x85>\x97\xb9\x80?`\xef\xcf=\x05&\x92>E\x0bx=\xc0\xb5\x8f> n\xa8>\xb9R\xaf\xbe\x1c\x88\x10\xbf\xd5e\xe6\xbd\xa3\xd6_>Nz\xcf\xbe\x9c\xb3E>\xe4\xdf\xcd>\xc5-,\xbf\xf5{U>\xffA\x81\xbf\xc0\x9b]>Y0\x98\xbdU\x01\xc8\xbf&\xc5r?\x9f\xa7\xcf=\xce\x1f\x15>\xae\xd03>\xe4:v>\xd9\xa1\x8a\xbe\xe8\x8e\t\xbfe\xa5\x08\xbf \x98\xc1>t\xc2:\xbf\x08\xd7b?\x1dA==\x1ck\x00?\xceU\xeb>\x84\xad\r=\x05\xd7\x8f?X\x96\x82\xbe\xd9\xd18\xbf@31\xbe&7\x05?lpw>o\xbe\x17\xbe@*\x95\xb9\x1d>V<Z\x05\xf2\xbc$9\xa3\xbf\xc7\xf2\\?U\xff\x81\xbe0\x17C\xbf\x03\xe71\xbf\xd2\xb6\x89A/\x1f\x81A\x9b[\x84A\xdf\xd6\x82B\xac\xfe\x82B6\xb0\x85BZ-eAH\xb9mAt\x11WA\xe86\x85B#\xac\x86B\xbb:\x87Blm\x85B\xdb\x8f\x85B\xf2V\x86B,\xf8\x86B\x94X\x84B\xa5\xb7\x86B PoB\xf6\x98nBIYjB\xcd\x9d\xa1A\x7fW\xaeAZ\x1a\xa7A\xe6?lC\xbfSlC\xe5\x82kC\x8e+~C\x89\xa2~C\xef`~C\xf8\x1d\xd3B\x1e\xf4\xd2B\xbf^\xd3Bi=\xe6\xbebiZ?W\xc2\xfb\xbe\x1c\x11f\xbetZ]\xbe(\x9f\x93\xbf\x9910\xbe\xe1$\n?\x07\xe4\xad\xbe\x8d9\x83?\x12A>\xbfn.$\xbft\x82\xd1\xbe\x8c\xd9R?"\xd9\xd9=p\xf7\x1e?\xe5\xebX?\xa5tJ>\t\x91q\xbd\xd4p\xd9\xbe\x96\xf6N\xbez\x8c\x97\xbe\xe8.Z\xbf*\x02]>d\xdb\xd0\xbe\x84\x91\xb6\xbe V\xa7\xbe\xa7\xa8i>\xca\x88"=\x99\xe4\x0b?\xceK\x80\xbf_\x95k\xbd\xf2Gy>\xd1\xde\xc1>2\x1a\xf1\xbd\x11\x1c\xed\xbe%m\x1f\xbe"\xf2">HX\xe4=\xf5\xa4\xc2>\x91\xf7\x8d\xbe\x16\xec\xcc>\x02\x8bg\xbe\x03n\x84>\xbe\xca\x94?\x19\x80\xe0\xbe\xe1\xd9\x17?q\x15=?\xdf\xa4]\xbd\x896\x1d\xbeM\xe5h>N\xf7\x07?i\x9c\xaa>\x01\xef\x15?\xc6V\xcb>\x8c\x1cv>\xe5\t\x9c\xbe\xedz\xee>w\xc5<>\x1a\xed\x99\xbd\x1a\x1e\xd9\xbejY4\xbf\xcb->\xbe\xa7$\xaf>\x93\x99D?T\xe4\x0b?\xa4\xb1\xbb>\xa2E\x88\xbe\xfc\xcd\xdc\xbeF\xe9/\xbfH\x08\xc6>)\x8ek?\xb1\xde\xa5BK\x10\xa4B9w\xa5B\xe4*}C|\xcb|C\xd4\xc4|Cy\xe1PC#\xe6PCp\xb3PCQ1\x8dA\xae\xff\x90A\xcd\x9e\x8cA\x83\xa1\x19\xbf2\xa1z\xbf`\rU>z\xc6\x05?=\x89\xb9>\x85\xb9\x8c=~\x18\xc6<`K\x89>\x93\xd2\xf4>\xae\x04p\xbf\xcd\x0e\xcb\xbe \x8f\xa2\xbf\x0b\x15\xb1>O\x9b\xd7=\x82\x04\x04?*\x8b\x04\xbf\xbd])?I\xf3\xf5\xbeTWT\xbf\xb8 \x14\xbfDc,?\x17\xd9\x17?\xf6\x1b`?\x88&K\xbd\x07\x82\x00>8q?\xbd\x85\xca\xf0>\xbd\xec\xd4>9q\xa0=H\x0f\\>X\x8d\x83\xbd\xae\xe0\x04\xbdG&\x0b?\xf1\xd4W\xbf\xa1\xbdY\xbd\x80#r\xbe\xd0\x7f\xe3>\x8a\x19\r\xbf*w]\xbe\xc6\xf6\xc6>.8S\xbe\xb7\xacM>\x1a\xd2\x11\xbf\xe7\xe9\xf4\xbeH\x18=?e@#\xbfJ=c=\x0f35?\x03G5\xbf\x13E!>\'\xe3S?\xb7/\x93\xbd\xc6\xf00\xbf_L\x16>t2\x01?h\xfe\xb8\xbe\x9c\xaa\xa7\xbet\x96\xd4\xbd\x82\xfe\x90>]\x97\x84>\xbe\x18F;\x93\x0c\x1a?\xb7\x1e\xb2<\xa7n\x06\xbf\xaa\xf8\'\xbf\xa9\xe2q>\x88\xc8\n?\x95R\xf5\xbe\xa9\xc7\x9f>\xcd\x07\xb4A\xc4P\xb3A\xfe\xc4\xb3A\n\xa3hC\x9a\xc9hCH\x16iC\xb7\x0f\x7fC\x83h\x7fC\x8c\xf6~CSG\xa7BMa\xa6B\x80>\xa6B\xef^+\xbf8O\xcc\xbd\xb4=\xd3\xbd\x97\x1d\xae>k%\xc2\xbe\xee)\x0b\xbd\x1a\xf8\x85?\x83H\x86\xbf\xd4\xc7\xdf>c\xd3\xd3\xbe\xa4\xf8\x9f>\xdcL\xc8>\x06\xb0\xa5\xbe\xc9\x02\t\xbe\x8c3\xd1\xbdXD\x9b\xbe\xb7\x8e\xd1>\xc6V9?\xe8\x87\xa8\xbf\x103\x1e?\x81\x9e~\xbf\xd4b\r\xbf\xf9\xdco?\xef\x99\x19?\txq\xbe \x82\x00\xbfAb\x18>w\x97C\xbf\x82\xa5\xe9>\xd0d\xd0>\xd1\xbft=\xe6\xdd\xa6:\xd5\x96\x06??\x91(\xbf\xb4N\xad\xbe\xa7\xf6\xd8\xbe5<-\xbf\xba\xbe\x9b\xbc\xb7q\n>\xecL\x1d=\x00\xca4\xbf\xa3f{\xbe\xfe\xc6\x19\xbe\x1c\xb1\x1a\xbf\x08\xaeB\xbf\x92\xa98?\x06\x94\x1c>r\xd9\xe7\xbb\xd8P\x0b?7o\xf8\xbeS\x90C?>\xf9\x17\xbf\x10\xf2\x1c?\xd0U.\xbd\x8fb\x00\xbe\xc3>Q?\xe1\x14\xb4=\xdd\x07j=\x89\xf1\x9d>q\xf7\x8b\xbf\xd2\xc4\x93>\x94sL\xbfXO\x1d\xbf\xb8:\xfd\xbe\x1b\xebH=p\xd3/?=\x98\x0c?O\x1cM?\xf99\xc5>\xcfy\xfd>\x8c\xe7\xb6\xbd\x12O\x0e\xbfR@\x00C\xaf\xeb\x00C>\x0b\x01C\x1fM}Cpo}C`\xb7}C\xd2OnC\x10xmC\xe9\xa5mCv\xad1B\xbc%-B\xf3\x8f/B\xea\xe3\x87\xbed\x89\x1d\xbf\x96%\xb3>\x8a\x8a#?h\x10\xae>\xefx\x12=\xfb\xcb\x91\xbe\xe1\xcf\xcf>A\x96%?I \xdf\xbdbBO\xbfj\xaeb\xbf=\x0e\xcc<\x18\xb4\x87>;c\xef\xbe\xaf\xf5\r\xbf\x1b\xe1-\xbffy\x8c=9*\xaa>rr\xb1=\xb9\xef)?\x18\xab\xd4\xbec$\xd6=\x85\xaco\xbd\x0b*0?p\x99/\xbe\x99\xb4\x0c\xbe\x1e\xb94?\xad\x05P>O\xda9\xbd\x8d)C\xbf\x92x\xc6>"k\x95?:\x9e+>\x08\xdd&\xbf\x82\x9c\x83\xbeJ\x8e\x01\xbcQ}\xb4>n\x82\x1c?\x86#t=\x1f0\xd8\xbe\xa8n\xa3\xbf.3\x1b\xbf\xb9\xc6\x07\xbfq\xb0\xad=)\x9cm\xbe\x93^N?o}F>\xcd\xcf\xd2>&\xc4+\xbd\xc9\x05\xc8>\xb3D.\xbe\xec\xbc\x01>\xa6\x15\xd3\xbd\x1a\xf7#?x\xf3\x13?J\xb3\xea>\x97\x02>\xbe\xc3\x81\x1c\xbdu\x01r\xbe|\n/\xbd\xb7\x84\x1d?\xbb\x0e\xf8\xbeO\x8cp?\xdf\x91b\xbfw\xc0*\xbea\xbe)\xbd\xd0F;\xbf\x8d\xa3\xba>\x80\x98hBb9oBWFlB\x1eDyC\xfa\x87xC\x8b\xddxC*D}CK\xce~C\x18\x99~C\x80\xe2wB\xc2\xd4zB3OvB[)K?\x0b\xa0\x12>\x82!\x15\xbfB \x00>\x00t\xca>G\xb7+?\xdf\xfd\xf4>\xe7\x00\xaa>wZ\x83=L\xd8\x8b\xbe\x0e\xc5\xcc\xbe\x9d\x7f==\xd4KE>\x02\xf4!>\xbe\xb0%\xbf\xbf\xd8\xc8\xbe\x85>\xfb\xbe\xeb\xf9{?.\xdb\xce=@\x84\x1d\xbf=\x8e\xd1>\xd8\xe1\x8a\xbf\xcc\x95o=\x9aK\x85?>\x151?\x07\xac\x03\xbf\xcb\xe2\x17>\xae).\xbe\xa4=\xf7>\xb8\xf7(\xbf2\xd3\xe1\xbd\xedw\x9c=\\\xda\x8d>\xcc5\xe7>g\xb8\x15?\x91Vb\xbf4r\x80?\x8e\x03\xe6\xbeU\xf3\xde\xbe\'\xb4\x85\xbf\xec\'\x98\xbf\x0f\xe3\xba\xbe\xa3_|>+X\xb4\xbe\xaf\xdf\x1c?M\x9d\n\xbf\xa1\x86\xe6\xba\xae\rC?i\xf5U>\xa0Ab>\xda\xb9\xc1=\xa7\xc2\x81\xbe\xcd\x9a\x06\xbf\xcb\xa9\xb5\xbdd\x15\xd3>ed\n>\xa3\xbbp\xbf\xb7\xfat>\xa3\xe6\xd7\xbd\x82\xca\x98?6x\xfd\xbe\x9d.O?\x8d\xb5\xa1<\xd6\x02\xa3>.\xc5q\xbe\xcd\xd7F\xbe\xd8\xcbj\xbe\x0b\xbb\xc0>\xc8.\xa7>i\xe4\xd0\xbe\x00\xcf\xb9>)\xffG=\x9a\xc7\x04C\xa1\xee\x04C\xf17\x05C,\xd3}C\x12\xf2}C\xa8-~C\xcf=:Cj\x7f:C\xda\xad:C\xb7i\x8c@\x8c=\xc0@\xc0\xf4\x97@\xd4K=\xbe\xd3\xa2\xdd\xbd\\o(>s\xcf\xb5\xbf\xd48\xcf\xbe<\xbf\x83\xbfU\x97\xf8<\xfa\x89\x02?\x81%\x7f\xbd$\x7fh\xbfQa\x05=\xb2\x0c\xb9\xbce\x9d\xa1?\xb4\xf4\x02?\xe1<\x7f>;\x8f<\xbf\xa6\xb9\xd9\xbe8\xe9B\xbf\xaa\xc3\xa0\xbf\x85\xb4T\xbd =\x01?\xf1\xb6\xc4>\x1d\xf1\xbb>r\x80\xb5\xbf0i\x06\xbf\xc1\x10t\xbe\x9f\xd4\x92=\t\x19]\xbf2\xe3\x1e\xbe\x08\'#\xbf\xd3K\xf2\xbc\xfep\x96\xbe\xa6\xb7Y><\r_?\xd6j\t=Yy\x07\xbf`\x91e?2\xe2\x1d>r\r\x17\xbe\x9c\xfe[\xbd\xd6\x88\xe8=\x1c\xea\xcb\xbe;\xf7!?j\xc0(\xbe\xb8\xc1\xb6>Uf\xf8>\'\x05E\xbeFA\xc8\xbe\xab}\x8f\xbc\x85\x089<\x07\xb9R?\x023\x19\xbf3\xcd{>\xd85\x07>\x1a`\x02\xbf3\xb6\xb6\xbd&\x94u?\xedY\x8b>\x0e\xa8\x82>}s\xe4\xbd<\x87\x8d\xbe1\x8cy>G\xe9E?\xd3J\x87\xbe\xc2\x0f\xc1?\xea\x1bx\xbe\x95]\xea\xbe\x00x+\xbf\xac\xd1\xb1\xbe\x92\xe5\rA\t\x98\x0fA\x1aL\x10A\x8fOMC\xb2TLC\xc5\xa4LC\x06vxC\\\xc0xC(\xaawC]shB\x95\x0ejB\xda\x0biB\x89.\xa1\xbf6\xcd\xc6>\x8by\x84\xbf\x05\xfa\xd5>\x8b\x1aN\xbdz\xd9&\xbd\xbf\x13\xda>\x9cke?\xe4gl>\x85\xa0P>\xfe\x95\x9f<\xa3\xab&\xbf[^E?c`\xa1\xbe\xe8\xbc\xa6=E\xd3\xe3>\xa7\x7f\xd0\xbc\x89FI\xbd_\xba\xa8\xbf5?Z\xbe\x0e\xban>\x8e\xf1\xf0>\x9f\xe8\x05\xbdQ\x1a\x8b\xbaJ,\x04?\xcd\x0f\x90?\xd1\xd8\xa1>\xa6\xb3y>\xfd^">5\xb1<\xbe\x0c\x08\xce=:l\\>\xd0\xc8G\xbf\xb8\xe2d?\x85\x02B\xbf1\x05z\xbfP\xf6\x1e\xbe\xdc(\x06\xbf\xcde\x0f\xbd\xf4B\x1e\xbe\xa3QJ\xbd\x04Z\x06\xbf\x03L\x00>b\xbf\xa3>\x026\xf0>\xfe(0>\xc5\xfe_\xbe\xae\x05/\xbf\xd8F\xc5\xbb\x05\xf1\xad\xbe\xb4x\xfe\xbe\xbf\xfe\xe3=\xd6\x9a*\xbfin<>\x90#!>\x04i3\xbf\x8c;-\xbf\x95\x8e\x13\xbf/\xf1j=H\xb7\xd4=\x1d\n\xfe>`\xa1\x0e\xbf\x1f\x8f\xd7=\xd0C\xfd=\xb3G.\xbe\xef\xc3\xf4>\n{\x0c>\x9d\xff\x10?l\xa2\x8b>iG\x18\xbfKE\x81>\x94\xd0\xa5\xbei\xdc\xfbBw\x8f\xfdB\xb7@\xfdB\xd8\xc9~C\xb0\xb8}Cp\xd9|C\x8c<6C\xa2\xe75CG\xec5C@\x11I>j\xe7\xec=\xd5\x87;\xbf%7\x9f>\xebG\xb5\xbd\xbf<\x1f\xbf/\x98\x1b>\xeaj\xd4>\x0c\xa6\x16\xbe\xb1\xb2\xf3>L\xc9\xb2\xbe\xf6"\x08\xbe\xad\xe4\xe1\xbe\xd2\x1eY?\xe9\xbb(\xbfQ\xce\xf5\xbe\xf4<\x9d\xbeSq\xb9>\xbb\x1d\xb8>\xd3\xad\x01?@\x89\xac\xbe~-\xa0\xbe\x99\xa7\x80>\x9f*\x9c\xbe\xaf6\xff>E\xbe\\?\xcb\xb7\x0c\xbf#!\xc7\xbe)4\x94=\xda)T\xbfe\x7fk\xbe\x94\x00\x15?\x8e\xd2J\xbb\n\xe2\x03\xbfV\xcb\xa5>\x8d\r\x15>\xdci\x16\xbf\x10\xff\xd9\xbe\xf8.~?\xbc\xbc\xb2>\xdd\x06\xca\xbe\xef\xf62\xbf^\xfc\x04\xbfwY">~\x90\x98\xbe|\xdf\xde\xbem&2\xbfx\xac\x8e?\x80\x99\xdf=Wm\xec\xbcm\xdb\xa5\xbe\r\xfe\xdb>\\\x1cg\xbed\x9c\xbe\xbe<\x9b\xaa=q\xa9W?\xd5\x91\x12?"$\xbb\xbaH\xd7\x1e>\xc6N\x97\xbe\xaa\x8d\x8a\xbf\xa5\xff\x06\xbf\xe9u\xd5\xbe\x1f\xa1*>\rr\x1f\xbf\xfdG\x15\xbf\xd6\xfd\x0e\xbe/,\xe7>\xa4NU\xbe]\x99j=\xd0Lq\xbdk0\xa2\xbf\x97\xeb\x95B\xfe\xdb\x95B}!\x95B\xecjzC\xe8\xc7yC\xf6\xeczC\xfcbpC\xa8{pC\xa8\x05pC4\'aB\'\x03bB\n\x9eeB}2\x01?\x14H\x8f>\xf5U*?K|7>\xefx1\xbf\xd2\x1b\x9a?WL\x8a\xbf\xfb\n\xc2\xbe\\\xb4\xa5\xbd\xe1\xdc\xd3\xbd\xf9\xcf\xc3\xbc\xfc\xda5>%\xd4\x02\xbf\xf8\x7fy\xbb\xa2-\xe1>\xc1\xbdP\xbf)\x8c6?Z\xd6\x08?\xd1\xe2X\xbeJ\x00\xd9\xbf\xefo,?\xff\xb5\xa9>]\x92\x02\xbe\x8b\xb8\xfa\xbd\x03\xc1\xdd>\xfa\x04\xb6>\xce7\x06>\t4\x06\xbf\xaf\xea\xd2\xbd?1\x04\xbe\xfa\xcb\xfa=\xfc\xd8\x86>\x84\x96\x85\xbe\xe1\xc2i\xbf\xd4\x06J\xbeK\x0f\x0e?*-\x9d>H\x02\x03?n\xf9\xa0\xbd\xd9\xea\x18\xbe\xb0\xd5\x15=\x1b\x87\x08\xbf\xaa\x0cE?\xa8b\x9a\xbd\xa2n\\\xbf\xc6\x82)\xbf\x18\x1e\x89\xbf1lN?\xd8\xa1\xc4\xbe\xb5\x90\xe7\xbe\x86P??9\xfd\xa4=c\xcaH\xbfb\x04#\xbe\xfd\xfb`?\x16\xd7#=\xeb\x9c\xad?\xdeD\xef>\x1e\t\xd0\xbel\x99\xb6\xbd\xd5\x92\xc7\xbe\x9b\x81?>\xd1\x9c\x01?\xaaj\xab>\xf4\xa8N>;\xf6F= s%\xbf\x7f\xf0\x91>wW\\\xbf\xd1D\x92A\xec\xef\x98AC\xfc\x9cA\xf8\x9b\\C\xdb*]Ck\x1f]C\xe9;~C]Y~C\xef*~C\xd0\xee%C\x04u%C\x1f-&C\xba\x08\x86>\xd8\xb5\x07?\xc2\x17\x93\xbe<\xaf\xaa?(\x8f\x9a\xbe\xdeFP>ww\x11\xbfo\xe2J\xbd\x7f\x14\xb8\xbd\xc7.0\xbf\xb1\xbf2>|\xd2e\xbf\x9d\x0c\xa5?_\x11\x11\xbf2m\xc2\xbea\xcc5=?R\x81\xbf\xa7\x9f\x97?\xfd\xae\xe5\xbe\x82\xbd\xe6\xbe\x86\tA\xbe\x9eP\x8a\xbfJey=TY\x08>\x11\xaa\xa9\xbf\xc5\xb9^\xbe\x97\x8c2\xbf\xbc(\xd4\xbe\x90(W\xbcU\xcc\xed>=\x1bh\xbe\xe6\xf36\xbe \xe3e\xbf\xea\x8e??T*\xa2?\x81\xb8c?\xa5"\xd3>a\xa3\xe0>\xdc\x15\x8b\xbe\x04P\x15\xbf\x8b\x1bV>{\xa9:\xbd\x10(w>\xc8\x9a1?a\x06}>\xb8\xfb\x14\xbe\xa9S\x06?\xb5\xb4\xba>\x03\xaf\xed\xbe\x05)\xfb>_\xa1\x84>l\x85\x12>\xbfpv\xbf\x90u:\xbe^c9\xbf\xeb\xb1\x82?\xe0\x9f\x0f\xbf\xa1;\x1a\xbfP\xa3\xc6>\x08\xa0\xbe<\x82\xc0\x94\xbd%\xdeJ\xbf\xc3\xd3\x03?\xdb\xa7 >\xee\x01\xf2\xbdw\xed\x08\xbf\xd6XP?f\'\x0b\xbe2\x05\xde\xbe\x0b\\@@\x19]\x1c@\xa3ZE@\xb3bJC\xc0{JC\xab\xe4JC\x1b\xea}CuK}C\xee\x93}C\xc5\xa4ZCC\x8a[C\xf7\xabZC\x8f\x04\nB\x91y\rB\x9e\xf7\x0cB\x9d\x19\xdd>\xf4\xbc\t?\x83\xfd\xf3>Z\x07\xe9\xbe e\xd7>\xe0\xf2\xbf>\xbc\xb2{\xbf\x07}\xf0\xbc\xc0\x1fI>\xcc\x12\x04?{yd=qY\xa6\xbe\xad7C>\x84\xc1\x82=\xbbn\xd9\xbe\xc0\x84,?\xe3\x12\xa2\xbe\x8a\x81(?\x06\xccH\xbe\xec\x95T>\xcb\x13\x8b\xbe\xb5I\xe9\xbe&_\x02>\xafq\x04?\xad\xbe\xfb\xbd\xbaiU?\xbe\xca\x16\xbfJ^F\xbf>6\x89>\xd8\xac\'\xbf\xcaJ\xe9>I_\x8f>\xa2)\x8b?f.D>\xf2"\xde>LD\xca=(Ox\xbdD\xf7v=\xec\x01;\xbf\x1c!l>\x92\x98">d\xdcM\xbe:\xfcF\xbf\xd0I\x82>|\x0b\xcd\xbd\xd3W\x0b?b{\xac\xbct5\x0b?\xc5\xc9?\xbe\x8fh\x91?\x93\xdc\xcf\xbe\x8by\xee\xbd\xcc %?\xca\xc6\xd0>\x8c\x92\xec\xbck\x8d\x85\xbf\x0bt\x9b\xbf\x92Z0\xbf\x1fW\x1a?\xfd\x904?P`.>\xa0\x84\xb1>t\xe0\xaa=|\xa5\xfa\xbe>zC?\xca\xf4\x01\xbf\x00\x0e\xc5\xbd\xb9\xcb\xeb\xbe\xd7Gt?\xf4\xff\x17B\xbe\x12\x17B\xfc\xe8\x19B\x18\x18~C\x1b1~C:T}C\x9c\xf7}C\xfa\x0e~C\xaa\xc2}C\xa4H\x99B\x15\xf4\x9bB\xdcq\x97B\xfbWh=r< \xbfDQi>\xfd\xf6\x02\xbf\x10&\xbb>\xb5\x90\xff>\xab\xf2Y\xbfg<9\xbeh\xc6]?S\xe2\xa5>s\x7f\x95>\x18^F\xbf\xcd\x8ac>\xf9\x87s>\xf3\xaf\xac>\xed\x18\xc2>m\x7f\x04?y\xf8i>\xaa\x93<\xbe/\x9d\x04\xbfS\x17\x8b>\x88\r\x9b>\x18\xc4Q?V\x1c,?W\\\x1e?yW\xb9\xbe`.m>\x1e?&\xbf\xe2\xff/>\xa8\x88\xe1=\xd8\xaa\x82>\xc4\xce\xc1\xbe\xed\x0c%\xbf7\x14b>\xac\xb3\x1e?\x87j\xb9\xbf\xb1\xf3\xba>\xdf=%\xbf\x003:?(\xc9\t\xbfD\x17\xc4\xbdt\xf2\n?\xce\x19\xd6=+\xc0\x8c>\xf3mL?\xde\xef\x9b?@\x87\x9d>\xe4\xf7\xc3\xbe4\xe2\x9e\xbe\x97\xfb\x01?\xb76\x9b\xbd\xc1\xb8\x0e?\xb5(\xd6>\xf3\xa3\xa8\xbe}$\x9d>\xd3\x1e6?\xc4H\x8e\xbe\xa10\x9b>`\x10#?\xf2i\xf4\xbeX\xf6\xe0=^L\x14\xbftX\x04\xbf\x8e\x17\xb7>\xe3\xa0\xc8>o\x8e~\xbd;&??\xe3\xa6A?u\xa61\xbeG\xde\xfaA\xb2\xf6\xf6A\xed\x03\xf0A\xfb\x93_CE\x02`Co\xa1`C)\xc8}C\x1bx}C\x11\xed}C\xf9\xe2\xe4B\x06\xa4\xe4B\xd7\xdd\xe6B\x9a\xce\xcd?\xda\\\x88?\x8f[\x8f?Wx\x16?Q!\x11\xbe\x8b\x0b=?\x13)\xf9:\xb9\x04\x9a\xbf\xf1\xcf\xcb\xbe\xb2\xca\x8f\xbf\xa7\xa1\x87>\xfb\xaa\x1c\xbfxU0\xbf\xf7\xfd\xa9<\xab\x03\xab==\x91F>\x13\xdcB\xbf\x80\x1b\xda>\xf7\xd55\xbeN\xca\x8b<\xf5i\x1a>:-L\xbe\x9f\n\xe4\xbdZ\xce\x89\xbe\x99P\x91>\xc9\x10 \xbf\xb9Oh>\x856\x02?\xf5\xa3\x0e<V\xa3\xab\xbde\xc2$>\xe1Ye?;\xfe\x93\xbd\xdf~\xfe=]\x18\xa5\xbe\xd0\t\xe1<\x9e:\x0e?K\x1a\xab?\xe0\x95O?\xf4\xb9\x1d>\xc5\xd4\xda=[Q@\xbf7`1>_9\xec\xbd\x1a\x1e\x1c\xbf\xe4\xd7\xf7\xbe\xf0#\x17\xbdY%\xa0=\xdd\xf8\x1a\xbf:B\xf8\xbd\xcd*\x8f>h\xc6x>x6\xf6=\xc1\x0c\xa6\xbf\xea\nw\xbf\x8d\xa4K\xbf\xcf\xc8\x7f\xbezH#\xbf\xe5\xf0S>$\xc5\x04\xbf\x97\x8fF\xbe\x0b\\\x95\xbeh\xc8\x89\xbf\xa0W\x1c?\x9c!\x92?<\x1c\xc4>\xc5\x13\x14>\xa3nE\xbd4\x01\xa9>A\x82\x84\xbf \x0b\xac\xbf\x1a\xf0\x9d>\xe5\x03\x05Ck\x08\x04C\x8aC\x05C\xc2\x9e}C2h}C\x1d)~CS\t~C\xa4b~Cf\xa8}C\x81mOB\x16EOBF\xc0QBs\xf9r\xbfo\x8aP\xbf\xb4\x80\xca>Y\xa2\xc0>L\x176\xbf\x98T$\xbf\xbc,\x95?G\xe4M>D\xd0\xa4\xbd\xb7\xb5\x16?G\x08B?X\xfdI>\x8e\x0e\x9a>\xeb\x93\t>\xe9\xfe\x9c>t\x8cM?RS\xa6>4\x15@=\xf2N\xc0\xbe\xc4|\x1f>E\xe4\x80\xbd|@\xf2>\x97\xb11\xbeY\xcd&\xbf\xe8j\xf0\xbeYG8>\xc4\x1a\x11\xbeY\xe0m\xbf\xf3?\x06\xbe\xf4\xbe\x9c>-\x88Z\xbek\xd0\xfd\xbeD\xed\x8c\xbd\xa8\x92\x0c?\xd4\\\x1b>F\xbe\n\xbf]\xaf+?x\xd7\x16\xbe\x81-\x03?\xd79\xb2\xbd\x95\xdf\xa6>\xe0\xe26?B\xbb"\xbf!\x11\xf5>\x87\xfa\x0f\xbf\xe4\xced>\x92h\xe9>\x8a\xac\x13\xbf\x9c\xe5@\xbeFJ\x1e\xbf\xf1#\xaf>\xbc\x1f\xa7?\x9e\xc2\xa1\xbe\n\xb1\xac>~\x94\xa0\xbei\xef\x17?\x1c\x9b\x94?k\xef\xdb>\xb3\xfb\x93\xbfT\xfa\x89\xbe\xd1\xe8z?\xc6\xac\x1f\xbf&\xb8\xcc\xbe\xa1|\x00?\xab\xc9\x16?\xb2\x00\xbb>\x9a\x10\xe4=\xeb\x85\xd1\xbe\xaa\x12\xae\xbe\xc2\xc4rB\\8pB\x04nuB}\x89qCj\xb4qC{\xb5qC\x97$~C\x92g~C9\x87}C\x0b\\~C\x8a\xc3}C\xee\xd3}C\xbd/RB\xde\xc0PB\xcfGNBf\xc4W?[L\xa3>\xf5\x84\xc5\xbe\x07\x07\xf4>\xb5\x9b\x8d\xbe\x9dG\xde\xbe\xb2\x05\x85>\x02\xe0\xa7>V\x91\x93>\xc5\xfb\xbb\xbe\x15\xd4\xcf>$\x91\xf3=\x17\x94C??F$\xbfa"\x11?_\x01\x00>0\x1f\x82\xbfC\x02o>\x9a\\H\xbf(\xcfZ\xbf)B\x97\xbcjk\x91>\xaf\x9c\xb5\xbe\x8a\x1aF?""N>5Zw>\x83\xb91?1\xecO>\x8b\xfa\xee>\x9d\xef\x9e=\xf0\xc4\xe9\xbe\xa5\x04\xe0<\xd9\xca\xb0?\xabs\xed\xbe\xad\x12\x80=\x06\x9d\x02\xbf\\\n&\xbf}\xd2\xae\xbe\xcd\xfeC?\x10i\x9d>(\xafm?>#\x9c=\xe4\xd8\x92=\xdb9\xdc\xbeI\x11\x97>\x15\t\xd3=\x9e2\x1d?)c\xfb>\xef`\xab>\xc7\x85\xe4\xbe\xeb-\x0c\xbe\x91\xbe\xda>\\\xdf\x9e?\xcb\xafl\xbeN\xd2\x83\xbe\x8a\xb2:\xbevA\x8b\xbdrJh\xbe\x95\xe1\xd4\xbe\xa4r\x80?\xd7\xbe\x01\xbf$^u>\xbf\x1b6?\x8bi.?n\xd3\x93>\xe34\x12\xbdT(\x02?\xd2\xcd\xdc>\xb4t;>uJ\xf2B\x0b\x87\xf2B\xec\x90\xf1B\x1b\x18~CW|~C`\x8c}C^\x1e~CD~~C\xbaN~C\x8e)[C\xcc\x04[C\xf9\xb8[C\x9aG\x1fB\xc0\xa4 BI\'!Bd\xf3A\xbfm.\xd6\xbe\x13\x05\xc9\xbe\xe5\xb4\xeb\xbd\xe63\xeb\xbd#\x9c\x04\xbe\xdc\xa2\x06\xbf\tc\x02?\xda%o>\x92\x18S\xbf\x8dD\x8b?\x0e\x8f\xbe=@_*?\xd6\x12C?w+\x91=\xdf\xf3A?\xbd\xc4\x1c?\xcf\xa7\x1d?v\xbdA?\x07\x9b\xa1\xbc\x99\xca\xa9>\xacA\xfe\xbb.\x8aK\xbe\xda \xee>Q\xe2g<\x0br\x13?&\x8b|\xbd\x80\x9a,?\x03\xd7->`\xd3\xa1\xbd\xa3g[\xbe\xdf\x99\xe9<?\xe2\x06=?{\x04\xbe\xe1\xe7\x16?\xfeU\x11=\\\xc1O?H\xda\xf8\xbe\xe3\xfeu\xbd\xd5\xdf\x19\xbe\'w\xa7>{H \xbeN_1>\x8b\xe3\x8e=\xfdE\xe8>\xff\x173\xbd\xda\x07&\xbf\\ B=\xb3\xb2t\xbeh\x0cg\xbf\x8cw\xeb\xbc\x85\xa1\x18>\xe0\x0c\n?F\xdbL>\x02\xe3\x00?R\xe7\x0b\xbf\xb9\xcc\x08>,\x00<\xbd\xcd\x87\n?\x1a\xec\x90\xbeL&}9\x95\t\xd6\xbd)\x1a\xb0=\x0c\xf1\x87?\n\xd0;\xbfB`\xa4?\x8f\xd5\xd1\xbe~\x14r?L\xc7b>\xc5a\xf0B\xf7y\xf1B\xf13\xf3B\xae!~C\xfb\x0e\x7fC\x91=}C0INCK*NC\xc6\x8eNC\xaa\n\x91A\xeb\x01\x91Aor\x8bA\xbf\x0e.>3\x93D>U"->\xe7\xed\xd4>\xb1\xed\x8f\xbe\x07\x865?f\x85\xfe\xbey\xbe\x03?m\xbd\xd7=\\Z\x01?]z\xc6\xbe\x9ag\x81\xbfa\xa2:\xbe\xd1\x0c\x86\xbe\xdeu\xaa>~\x89\x8c?m{\x8a?\xad\xbb\x97\xbf@\x9d\xda>\xe9\x15\x86\xbeY\x80*\xbf\x8fd<\xbfH~9?\x1b\x81e?E\xac\xfd=\x08\xc32>\x86\x95\xb9\xbe\xb5\xcc%?\xc5s\'\xbd\xeb\xf1\xc2\xbe\x92\xab\x18?\x1e\x9a\xfe>p\x1d\xa8?Y"\x1a\xbd\xce\xd5{=0K]\xbf\xa2?\xe3>\x02\xba\xe6\xbeV\xe2\x94?\x1d\xe3\xfc>\xea\x9cg\xbe\xba\xb4R?\xa5q\x1e\xbf\xff\xf47\xbf\xf5\x80F>\xbclA\xbb\xe5\x14\x11\xbf\xd7y\xec\xbey3\x0f?\x86\x91\xc6=\xe8\x96~>\xf3d\x16\xbf1v\xd0>\xdd\xa1$>k\xa5 >\xf9k\x82>\xc1\xbf\x9f>\n\x94y<\x96_6?\xbb\x8b\xe5>\xa8N{>\xd4\xfd\t?\x1f\x1f6\xbe\x99\xd5\xd0;G\xc9\xde=nSa>\x9d\x00N?5z\x0c?-xJ>\xb5P\x08?\xa3\xed\x9a\xbe\xf7\xdc\x04\xbf.,#\xbe\xc3l%?l\x95R>2\x1a\xc1\xbd5=\xde\xbd\xf8\xecE>X\xfd\x89\xbe\x1d4\xaa\xbd\xe3\x9ag>vT\xbc:/s\xe3>\x17\xe0C?\x8d\x8f=\xbf<\\2=\xfbA?\xbf\x0cG\xf5=\xdb\x80\x12>\xbb\xad\x00\xbf\xea\x96C\xbfq\xa8\xf8>\xde\x84\xbb\xbeq\x19F\xbe\xe6\xbbw?_H\x1b\xbf(\xbe\x87\xbe%\xa1\xfe\xbaW\xc3Q\xbe%\x87D?\n\x8a]\xbe.P\xa0\xbe/u\xce?\x87&\x92>h\xb7\xf9>md"\xbc\x1d\xc6\x85\xbeG\x1a:?\xa0\xbc\x8c\xbe\xa8\xd8)>\xbd\xfb\xdf>\xaa;4\xbe!E\xf0\xbe\x90Ql>\x075\xdc?\\\xf9$\xbf*M\x83\xbe\xa9\xb6R=;\xb5\x94>\xec\xdd\x07>\xc6C\xcf\xbd\xf3fE\xbe!A\x8b\xbc\xe2\x18\xa1\xbe\xff\x89\x1a?tN\x8f>'
test_bytes = bytes(test_bytes)

test_image = np.frombuffer(bytes(test_bytes), dtype=np.float32).reshape(28, 28, 3)
# rescale to range 0 ... 255
test_image = np.clip((test_image - test_image.min()) * 255 / (test_image.max() - test_image.min()), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(16, 4))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(test_image)
plt.title("test_image")

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(255 - test_image)
plt.title("test_image - invert")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively you could also keep the image as floats and rescale to the range of 0.0 ... 1.0:

```
test_image = np.clip((test_image - test_image.min()) / (test_image.max() - test_image.min()), 0, 1)
```

Inversion is then `1.0 - test_image`.

PS: I also changed `fromstring` to `frombuffer` to suppress the warning.

Comment: But this image removed the "`random`" noise signal, I can't combine the  noise signal for model training in keras model. This image is one of Mnist dataset images.

Comment: I've updated the answer to *rescale* instead of *clipping* your data from -1.6953213 ... 255.40825 to 0 ... 255.